# For Python programmers, is there anything equivalent to Perl's CPAN?

Tags: python, perl

I'm learning Python now because of the Django framework.  I have been a Perl programmer for a number of years and I'm so used to Perl's tools.  One of the things that I really miss is Perl's CPAN and its tools.  Is there anything equivalent in Python?  I would like to be able to search, install and maintain Python modules as easy as CPAN.  Also, a system that can handle dependencies automatically.  I tried to install a module in Python by downloading a zip file from a website, unzipped it, then do:

`sudo python setup.py install`

but it's looking for another module.  Now, lazy as I am, I don't like chasing dependencies and such, is there an easy way?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

sammy, have a look at [pip](http://pip.openplans.org/), which will let you do "pip install foo", and will download and install its dependencies (as long as they're on [PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/)). There's also [EasyInstall](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall), but pip is intended to replace that.

Answer (score 11):

It might be useful to note that pip and easy_install both use the [Python Package Index (PyPI)](http://pypi.python.org/pypi), sometimes called the "Cheeseshop", to search for packages. Easy_install is currently the most universally supported, as it works with both setuptools and distutils style packaging, completely. See [James Bennett's commentary](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/dec/14/packaging/) on python packaging for good reasons to use pip, and [Ian Bicking's reply](http://blog.ianbicking.org/2008/12/14/a-few-corrections-to-on-packaging/) for some clarifications on the differences.

Comment: Now, a couple of years later, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14753678/260122 for a great overview of the packaging tool situation on Python.

Comment: Also, look into `virtualenv` and Python 3.x's native `venv`, they are the recommended method for predictability and isolation from what packages happen to be installed in your system.

Comment: For even better information, kept up-to-date, there's now https://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/current/ . (/via http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344076/differences-between-distribute-distutils-setuptools-and-distutils2/14753678#comment25440872_14753678 )

Answer (score 2):

If you do use `easy_install`, I'd suggest installing packages by doing..

```
easy_install -v -Z package_name  |  tee date-package.log
```

`-Z` (short for `--always-unzip`) unzips the `.egg` files to directories so you can then..

```
less *.egg/EGG-INFO/requires.txt  
less *.egg/EGG-INFO/PKG-INFO  
egrep '^(Name|Version|Sum|...)'  *.egg/EGG-INFO/PKG-INFO
```

On Sammy's original question, a couple of package indexes other than PyPI are:
[Scipy](http://www.scipy.org/Topical_Software)
and [Scipy docs](http://docs.scipy.org/scipy/docs/scipy) for scientific computing
[ohloh](http://www.ohloh.net/tags/python) with code metrics.