# Differences between distribute, distutils, setuptools and distutils2?

Tags: python, packaging, setuptools, distutils, distribute

### The Situation

I’m trying to port an open-source library to Python 3.  ([SymPy](http://sympy.org/), if anyone is wondering.)

So, I need to run `2to3` automatically when building for Python 3. To do that, I need to use `distribute`. Therefore, I need to port the current system, which (according to the doctest) is `distutils`.

### The Problem

Unfortunately, I’m not sure what’s the difference between these modules—`distutils`, `distribute`, `setuptools`. The documentation is sketchy as best, as they all seem to be a fork of one another, intended to be compatible in most circumstances (but actually, not all)…and so on, and so forth.

### The Question

**Could someone explain the differences?** What am I supposed to use?  What is the most modern solution? (As an aside, I’d also appreciate some guide on porting to `Distribute`, but that’s a tad beyond the scope of the question…)

Comment: I agree, Python packaging/installation has way too many alternatives with no clear guidance from the community.

Comment: @pixelbeat pip does support installing wheels (so-called binary distributions), that link is out-of-date.

Answer (score 899, accepted):

As of May 2022, most of the other answers to this question are several years out-of-date. When you come across advice on Python packaging issues, remember to look at the date of publication, and don't trust out-of-date information.

The [Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/) is worth a read. Every page has a "last updated" date displayed, so you can check the recency of the manual, and it's quite comprehensive. The fact that it's hosted on a subdomain of python.org of the Python Software Foundation just adds credence to it. The [Project Summaries](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/key_projects/) page is especially relevant here.

### Summary of tools:

Here's a summary of the Python packaging landscape:

#### Supported tools:

- **`setuptools`** was developed to overcome Distutils' limitations, and is not included in the standard library. It introduced a command-line utility called `easy_install`. It also introduced the `setuptools` Python package that can be imported in your `setup.py` script, and the `pkg_resources` Python package that can be imported in your code to locate data files installed with a distribution. One of its gotchas is that it monkey-patches the `distutils` Python package. It should work well with `pip`. [It sees regular releases.](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/releases)

  - <sub>[Official docs](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) | [Pypi page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) | [GitHub repo](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools) | [`setuptools` section of Python Package User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/key_projects/#setuptools)</sub>
- **`scikit-build`** is an improved build system generator that internally uses CMake to build compiled Python extensions. Because scikit-build isn't based on distutils, it doesn't really have any of its limitations. When ninja-build is present, scikit-build can compile large projects over three times faster than the alternatives. It should work well with `pip`.

  - <sub>[Official docs](http://scikit-build.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) | [Pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/scikit-build/) | [GitHub repo](https://github.com/scikit-build/scikit-build) | [`scikit-build` section of Python Package User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/key_projects/#scikit-build)</sub>
- **`distlib`** is a library that provides functionality that is used by higher level tools like `pip`.

  - <sub>[Official Docs](http://pythonhosted.org/distlib/) | [Pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/distlib) | [Bitbucket repo](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/distlib) | [`distlib` section of Python Package User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/key_projects/#distlib)</sub>
- **`packaging`** is also a library that provides functionality used by higher level tools like `pip` and `setuptools`

  - <sub>[Official Docs](https://packaging.pypa.io/) | [Pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/packaging) | [GitHub repo](https://github.com/pypa/packaging) | [`packaging` section of Python Package User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/key_projects/#packaging)</sub>

#### Deprecated/abandoned tools:

- **`distutils`** is still included in the standard library of Python, but is considered deprecated as of Python 3.10. It is useful for simple Python distributions, but lacks features. It introduces the `distutils` Python package that can be imported in your `setup.py` script.

  - <sub>[Official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/distutils.html) | [`distutils` section of Python Package User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/key_projects/#distutils)</sub>
- **`distribute`** was a fork of `setuptools`. It shared the same namespace, so if you had Distribute installed, `import setuptools` would actually import the package distributed with Distribute. ***Distribute was merged back into Setuptools 0.7***, so you don't need to use Distribute any more. In fact, the version on Pypi is just a compatibility layer that installs Setuptools.
- **`distutils2`** was an attempt to take the best of `distutils`, `setuptools` and `distribute` and become the standard tool included in Python's standard library. The idea was that `distutils2` would be distributed for old Python versions, and that `distutils2` would be renamed to `packaging` for Python 3.3, which would include it in its standard library. These plans did not go as intended, however, and currently, ***`distutils2` is an abandoned project***. The latest release was in March 2012, and its Pypi home page has finally been updated to reflect its death.

### Others:

There are other tools, if you are interested, read [Project Summaries](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/key_projects/) in the Python Packaging User Guide. I won't list them all, to not repeat that page, and to keep the answer matching the question, which was only about `distribute`, `distutils`, `setuptools` and `distutils2`.

### Recommendation:

If all of this is new to you, and you don't know where to start, **I would recommend learning `setuptools`**, along with `pip` and `virtualenv`, which all work very well together.

If you're looking into `virtualenv`, you might be interested in this question: [What is the difference between `venv`, `pyvenv`, `pyenv`, `virtualenv`, `virtualenvwrapper`, etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41573587/247696). (Yes, I know, I groan with you.)

Comment: Can anyone shed some light on what happened to distutils2? did the team  move back to working on distribute?

Comment: @makeramen: See [this thread on the mailing list](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2012-June/120430.html).

Comment: And is not looking any better: `'Distribute' is a now deprecated fork of the 'Setuptools' project.` @ PyPI Distribute page.

Comment: @KurzedMetal: I consider that deprecation warning on Distribute Pypi page a [bug](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/issue/13/pypi-home-pages-of-setuptools-and), as Setuptools Pypi page has not been updated.

Comment: @KurzedMetal, according to the SetupTools folks, setuptools 0.7 will subsume both distribute and the old setuptools restoring order to the universe. So things actually are set to improve considerably!

Comment: The [Python Packaging User Guide](https://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) will have the most up-to-date info on state of python packaging. It was noted by Nick Coughlan at the [2013 PyCon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ePFWp3oSfyU).

Comment: @Amro: `pip` is not an alternative to these tools but it does help with installing packages.

Comment: @Flimm: absolutely, but I feel like it deserves more than a short sentence under setuptools (which it depends upon) :) Anyway thanks for the comprehensive answer

Comment: If you're going to mention Bento, you should also mention Conda (http://conda.io) which is the core open-source technology used in the popular Anaconda distribution.

Comment: @Flimm The last edit is quite a while ago. Is Bento mature by now?

Comment: @MartinThoma Bento seems to be dead since mid of 2014.

Comment: The link to the docs of `distlib` is outdated - newest is https://distlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html.
Their self-described project status has also been upgraded from alpha: "The project has reached a mature status in its development: there is a test suite and it has been exercised on Windows, Ubuntu and Mac OS X. The project is used by well-known projects such as pip and caniusepython3."

Comment: where does 'wheels' come in?

Comment: Does Setuptools work very well with Anaconda (as opposed to Virtualenv and Pip)?

Comment: Ironically, this answer is now also badly out of date.  [PEP 517](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0517/), poetry, flit, `pyproject.toml` ...

Comment: I've updated the answer post. I didn't talk about Bento, Anaconda, wheels, and so on, to stop the answer from getting too big and from drifting too far from the original question.

Comment: You are a god, thanks for keep this maintained, I have this bookmarked and from time to time I comeback to see if I missed any changes, I've seen quite a bunch of the updates of this answer. Again: thank you very much for you time, like you said there's a lot of misinformation around, and I'm glad to have this as a reliable source of updated info.

Answer (score 255):

I’m a distutils maintainer and distutils2/packaging contributor.  I did a talk about Python packaging at ConFoo 2011 and these days I’m writing an extended version of it.  It’s not published yet, so here are excerpts that should help define things.

- **Distutils** is the standard tool used for packaging.  It works rather well for simple needs, but is limited and not trivial to extend.
- **Setuptools** is a project born from the desire to fill missing distutils functionality and explore new directions.  In some subcommunities, it’s a *de facto* standard.  It uses monkey-patching and magic that is frowned upon by Python core developers.
- **Distribute** is a fork of Setuptools that was started by developers feeling that its development pace was too slow and that it was not possible to evolve it.  Its development was considerably slowed when distutils2 was started by the same group. 2013-August update: distribute is merged back into setuptools and discontinued.
- **Distutils2** is a new distutils library, started as a fork of the distutils codebase, with good ideas taken from setup tools (of which some were thoroughly discussed in PEPs), and a basic installer inspired by pip.  <s>The actual name you use to import Distutils2 is `packaging` in the Python 3.3+ standard library, or `distutils2` in 2.4+ and 3.1–3.2. (A backport will be available soon.)</s> Distutils2 did not make the Python 3.3 release, and it was put on hold.

More info:

- [The fate of Distutils – Pycon Summit + Packaging Sprint detailed report](http://tarekziade.wordpress.com/2010/03/03/the-fate-of-distutils-pycon-summit-packaging-sprint-detailed-report/)
- [A Quick Diff between Distutils and Distutils2](http://wokslog.wordpress.com/2011/06/04/distutils-diff/)

I hope to finish my guide soon, it will contain more info about each library’s strong and weak points and a transition guide.

Comment: @Éric Araujo Please help me understand this, will distutils2 and distribute one day converge in a unique tool/library? Thanks.

Comment: No.  distutils2 takes some good ideas from setuptools/distribute, after standardization (PEPs) or not (for example, I mentor a GSoC student who’s adding a develop command and automatic scripts generation), but it won’t ever be a drop-in replacement: there are some parts we don’t want (eggs, VCS integration, etc.).  OTOH, distutils2 has some things that setuptools/distribute have not.  To ease transition, I think the distribute developers maybe will use distutils2 to support new standards and tools; I also think I remember the setuptools developer saying that he wants to support new standards.

Comment: Where does ez_setup fall in all this? Also are there any updates to the status of distutils2?

Comment: ez_setup is a bootstrap script that people can include in their repositories and source distributions so that setuptools is automatically downloaded and used when running setup.py.  distribute_setup is its distribute equivalent.  The maintainer of pip and I think that it’s inelegant and people should be instructed to install setuptools before running the setup script instead.

Comment: distutils2 is still slowly progressing.  Its inclusion in the standard library has been deferred from 3.3 to 3.4 because it was not ready.  For most people that does not make a difference as they use 2.x and can get d2 with pip.

Comment: @ÉricAraujo Sorry to hear about the delay.  I really hope it’s ready in time for 3.4!  I **love** Python, but the packaging has always made me bang my head against the wall.  (In other news, how is your guide coming?  If it’s finished, could you link it in your answer above?)

Comment: @AlexisHuet This kind of comment would be better if it would contain the link to the [comment below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14753678/131120) (which you can get from the `share` button).

Comment: you should perhaps update the answer to mention that `distribute` was recently merged back in `setuptools`. The fact that much of the information out-there is out-dated adds to the confusion

Comment: from the post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587507/how-to-install-pip-with-python-3 "distribute has since been superseded by [setup_tools] (pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools). – @wegry Aug 3 at 22:07" I'm assuming this is a false statement based on your post.

Comment: Distribute was merged back into setuptools, so the latest release of setuptools does supersede distribute.

Comment: So is the best current choice distutils2, or not? Setuptools bugs me downloading .eggs to the current project directory. Distutils2 seems to let you specify a path. Can't work out what the current state of all these tools is though. So confusing to a newcomer. Other languages just ship one system and stick with it. The Python community seems like it just wants to keep swapping and changing things.

Answer (score 5):

NOTE: Answer deprecated, Distribute now obsolete. This answer is no longer valid since the Python Packaging Authority was formed and has done a lot of work cleaning this up.

---

Yep, you got it. :-o I think at this time the preferred package is [Distribute](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute), which is a fork of setuptools, which are an extension of distutils (the original packaging system). Setuptools was not being maintained so is was forked and renamed, however when installed it uses the package name of setuptools! I think most Python developers now use Distribute, and I can say for sure that I do.

Comment: For the record, I accepted this answer because it told me the situation now (And the is fork of is extension of relation that the picture in the other answer just doesn't mention). And somewhere along the road I also learned that the documentation itself isn't usually sure what it's trying to say.

Comment: @VPeric, Indeed, the documentation reflects the fact that this aspect of python is in a state of flux/ a mess.

Answer (score 2):

I realize that I have replied to your secondary question without addressing unquestioned assumptions in your original problem:

> I'm trying to port an open-source library (SymPy, if anyone is wondering) to Python 3. To
>   do this, I need to run 2to3 automatically when building for Python 3.

You *may*, not *need*.  Other strategies are described at http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/pyporting

> To do that, I need to use distribute,

You *may* :)  distutils supports build-time 2to3 conversion for code (not docstrings), in a different manner that distribute’s: http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/pyporting#during-installation

Comment: Thanks, though we've already decided to solve the problem by writing our script to handle the conversion. And yeah, I knew there were other options than using 2to3, but SymPy is a complex codebase (around 200k+ lines last time I checked) and using 2to3 was the only realistic strategy. Thanks again, in any case!

Answer (score 2):

Updating this question in late 2014 where fortunately the Python packaging chaos has been greatly cleaned up by Continuum's "[conda](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/)" package manager.

In particular, conda quickly enables the creation of conda "[environments](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/intro.html)". You can configure your environments with different versions of Python. For example:

`conda create -n py34 python=3.4 anaconda`

`conda create -n py26 python=2.6 anaconda`

will create two ("py34" or "py26") Python environments with different versions of Python.

Afterwards you can invoke the environment with the specific version of Python with:

`source activate <env name>`

This feature seems especially useful in your case where you are having to deal with different version of Python.

Moreover, conda has the following features:

- Python agnostic
- Cross platform
- No admin privileges required
- Smart dependency management (by way of a SAT solver)
- Nicely deals with C, Fortran and system level libraries that you may have to link against

That last point is especially important if you are in the scientific computing arena.