# Adding 'install_requires' to setup.py when making a python package

Tags: python

To make a python package, in `setup.py`, I have the following:

```
setup(
    name='TowelStuff',
    version='0.1.0',
    author='J. Random Hacker',
    author_email='jrh@example.com',
    packages=['towelstuff', 'towelstuff.test'],
    scripts=['bin/stowe-towels.py','bin/wash-towels.py'],
    url='http://pypi.python.org/pypi/TowelStuff/',
    license='LICENSE.txt',
    description='Useful towel-related stuff.',
    long_description=open('README.txt').read(),
    install_requires=[
        "Django >= 1.1.1",
        "caldav == 0.1.4",
    ],
)
```

So I remade that with my own package description and information. When I build it though I get the following warning:

```
distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option:
```

Does `install_requires` work only on certain versions?

Comment: Possible answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295644 He said switching to Python 2.7.2 fixed the problem.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You need to be using setuptools instead of distutils.

Near the top of your script, try replacing

```
from distutils.core import setup
```

with

```
from setuptools import setup
```

Comment: Even better, you can import from `setuptools`, and if that raises an `ImportError` import from `distutils.core` instead.

Answer (score 33):

```
try:
    from setuptools import setup
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup
```

Comment: I tried this when installing jip for jython and found that it doesn't work. This piece of code you mention is exactly the code at the top of the setup.py and I get the warning message method by Niek.