# Python setup.py only for installation required packages

Tags: python, pip, setup.py

Is possible to avoid using `pip` and `requirements.txt` in favor of just using `setup.py` to install missing libraries but not having build all other stuff?
Normally it's looks like (and is run `python setup.py install`:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
   name="HelloWorld",
   version="0.1",
   packages=find_packages(),
   install_requires=['docutils>=0.3'],
)
```

And I wish to use only `install_requires=['docutils>=0.3']` to have those dependencies resolved and avoid all build artifacts.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question but may be an useful reading: https://caremad.io/posts/2013/07/setup-vs-requirement/ (just to see if it's a good idea or not)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the `setup` you are using, there is:

- `install_requires` with [setuptools](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html)

See also:

- https://packaging.python.org/requirements/
- [Adding 'install_requires' to setup.py when making a python package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810603/adding-install-requires-to-setup-py-when-making-a-python-package)

Comment: Can you see updated question regarding usage of `'install_requires`