# Python Packaging

Tags: python, package

Trying to create a python package. Seems to work, but i get a warning.
my setup.py is:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name='myPKG',
    version='0.02.01',
    url='http://someURL.02.01',
     packages=['scripts',
              'statistics'],
    author = 'Research-Team', 
    author_email = 'me@gmail.com',
    description='This is my package',
    scripts=['scripts/myScript.py'],
    entry_points={'console_scripts' : ['myCommandlineName = scripts.myScript:testRequireDecorator']},
    install_requires=['numpy >= 1.5.1', 'scipy >= 0.9.0', 'poster']
)
```

I get the following warnings. why, specifically, the two first user warning?

```
root@TK: python setup.py sdist
/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'entry_points'
  warnings.warn(msg)
/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'install_requires'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running sdist
running check
package init file 'scripts/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
no previously-included directories found matching '.git'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory '.'
writing manifest file 'MANIFEST'
creating myPKG-0.02.01
creating myPKG-0.02.01/scripts
creating myPKG-0.02.01/statistics
making hard links in myPKG-0.02.01...
hard linking README -> myPKG-0.02.01
hard linking setup.py -> myPKG-0.02.01
hard linking scripts/myScript.py -> myPKG-0.02.01/scripts
hard linking statistics/RunningMedian.py -> myPKG-0.02.01/statistics
hard linking statistics/RunningStdev.py -> myPKG-0.02.01/statistics
hard linking statistics/__init__.py -> myPKG-0.02.01/statistics
Creating tar archive
removing 'myPKG-0.02.01' (and everything under it)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295644/pypi-userwarning-unknown-distribution-option-install-requires (the first result on Google for 'UserWarning: Unknown distribution option')

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You're using distutils, but you need at least [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) in order to use those options.

```
from setuptools import setup
```