# How do setuptools, distribute, and pip relate to one another?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, distribute

I've been teaching myself Python through the book "Learn Python The Hard Way" (2nd Edition).  In exercise 46 it told me to read up on Pip, Distribute, and a few other packages.

The documentation for pip was clear enough.  It allows me to install/uninstall, and upgrade packages.  Reading the documentation for distribute, it basically seems to do the same thing:

> Easily download, build, install, upgrade, and uninstall Python packages

What's the difference between pip and distribute, and how do they relate to one another?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344076/differences-between-distribute-distutils-setuptools-and-distutils2

Answer (score 87, accepted):

[***2014-10 TL;DR:***
`distribute` is dead, use `pip`, the new `setuptools`, and, for binary distributions, `wheels`.  More below.]

---

**[Original answer]**

[Distribute](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute) <del>is</del> was a fork of the older [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) so nearly all comments that follow apply equally to Distribute and setuptools.  Setuptools was an attempt to fill in a number of holes in the even older Python standard library package, [Distutils](http://docs.python.org/3/distutils/index.html).  Setuptools added functions like automatic downloads of packages via a command-line interface, `easy_install`, and some level of dependency management.  However, a segment of the Python community is of the opinion that setuptools is too intrusive and has too much behind-the-scenes magic for some of its features.

`pip` is a higher-level interface on top of setuptools or Distribute.  It uses them to perform many of its functions but avoids some of their more controversial features, like zipped eggs.  `pip` also provides features not available in `setuptools`, like an uninstall command and the ability to define fixed sets of requirements and reliably reproduce a set of packages.  There is a more complete feature comparison [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip).

Why are there so many components (and there are more, like [`buildout`](http://www.buildout.org/))?  Lots of reasons: solutions must work across all of the major platforms on which Python is supported (i.e. Unix-y, Windows, Mac OS X), so building and installation present a *complex* set of problems; like many open-source projects, Python is essentially all-volunteer and many developers just aren't all that interested in packaging and installation issues; there is a natural conservatism about adding major new unproven features to the standard library; differences in opinions, etc etc.

At the moment, there is a project underway to provide a replacement for Distutils and possibly for some of the higher-level add-ons.  It is planned to be released in the Python 3.3 standard library as the [`packaging`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/packaging.html) package and as an add-on for older versions of Python as [`Distutils2`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Distutils2/).

To summarize, the current relationship is:

```
pip -> [ setuptools | Distribute ] -> Distutils -> Python core
                                    |
    3rd party packages              |      included in Python
                                    |
```

---

**UPDATE (2012-07)**: Prior to feature code cutoff for Python 3.3, it was decided that `packaging` was not quite ready yet for release in the standard library so it has been removed from the 3.3 release.  Work will continue on `Distutils2` which is available via PyPI and on what will be included in the standard library for Python 3.4.

---

**UPDATE (2014-10):** There have been further changes in the world of Python packaging since this answer was last updated.

- Most importantly, since mid-2013, the rift between `setuptools` and
  `distribute` has been healed and development activity [has been merged
  into a new `setuptools` project](http://pythonhosted.org//setuptools/merge.html).  `distribute` is now
  deprecated and no longer maintained; use the new `setuptools` instead
  but don't use its `easy_install` as an installer.
- `pip` has become the de-facto and blessed installer tool (for Python
  packages not otherwise provided by your platform's package manager)
  either in- or outside of virtual environments ([`virtualenv`](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or [`pyvenv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)).
- Instead of the old `setuptools` bdist `eggs`, [`wheels`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_wheel.html) have
  become the blessed binary distribution format for Python packages.
- [As of Python 3.4](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0453/), [a version of `pip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html) with `wheel` support
  is now shipped with the official `python.org` binary installers and
  source packages and it is anticipated that `pip` will also be
  included in the [next maintenance release of Python 2.7](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0477/) (2.7.9).
- `Distutils2` and `packaging` are now dormant.

More details in the new [Distributing Python Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/distributing/index.html) section of the Python 3 docs and the new [Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/index.html).

Comment: That's a great explanation, thank you!  I'm coming from a PHP background so it's kind of overwhelming how many overlapping modules/packages you have to understand.

Comment: Doing the same tutorial and your advice helped a lot. Thanks Ned.

Comment: There have been a *lot* of changes in the Python packaging world since the original answer.  See the latest update for more current information.