# Why does a virtualenv environment contain argparse, distribute and wsgiref?

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv

I am using `virtualenv` version 1.7.1.2 with `python` 2.7.3 to create virtual python ennvironments. But when I create such an environment and activate it, I can see the following packages are installed (using `pip freeze`):

```
argparse==1.2.1
distribute==0.6.24
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Why is that? What does that mean?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These are the standard packages, and will always follow with that version of Python and Virtualenv.

- `distribute` is pretty self-explainatory. [It's necessary for `pip`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8550546/1076493). Distribute also contains setuptools, but inside the package so not recognized with `pip freeze`. For more information about what it *actually* does check out your `env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.31-py2.7.egg`.
- `wsgiref` is actually a part of the standard library, but isn't recognized as so. There's a [bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue12218) on it, and it's fixed in Python 3.3+. Read more about it in [Why does pip freeze report some packages in a fresh virtualenv created with --no-site-packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627035/why-does-pip-freeze-report-some-packages-in-a-fresh-virtualenv-created-with-no)

I can't find out why `argparse` is there though, but my guess is because it's a dependency or something like `wsgiref`. [Finding package dependencies in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11148336/1076493) can be a bit hacky/painful though, especially if it's already installed in your virtualenv.