# How to distribute a Python package that adds an executable to the path?

Tags: python, linux, egg

I have a bunch of commands that I want to distribute to my colleagues. They want me to package it and add it to their path (`/usr/local/bin`)

How would I do this? We already have a Python repository. Is this possible in an `egg`?

Answer (score 4):

I dislike answering my own question but I have begun looking at this:

http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files

Seems like it might be the answer. I will update this answer when I try it out on Monday. Or, if anyone has used something like this before, answer yourself!

Comment: +1, but it's good idea to use `distutils2` or `setuptools` instead of `distutils` which are going to be deprecated.  See more details on packaging library selection here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344076/differences-between-distribute-distutils-and-setuptools

Comment: Thanks. Seems like this could be of great help and I will check it out on Monday: http://packages.python.org/distribute/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to [build an RPM](https://www.google.com/search?q=build%20rpm).  This is generally a pretty convenient way to install files to a predefined location.