# How to require and install a package using python 3.x distutils?

Tags: python, python-3.x, distutils

I have a program that uses `dateutil` from the package index. I would like to have setup.py check for for its presence and try to get it using `easy_install` if it is not there.

[The documentation for `distutils`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/distutils/setupscript.html#relationships-between-distributions-and-packages) seems to indicate that this can be done using the `requires` keyword in `setup()`, but when I try, it installs on a system without `dateutil` without giving a warning or installing the required package.

The only thing I could find on google was [this blog post about the same issue](http://blog.doughellmann.com/2007/11/requiring-packages-with-distutils.html) which did not have any answer either.

Am I using `distutils` wrong? Do I need to subclass `distutils.command.install` and do the checking/installing myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Automatic downloading of dependencies is a feature introduced by [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) which is a third-party add-on to `distutils`, in particular, the [`install_requires`](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#new-and-changed-setup-keywords) argument it adds.  See the [setuptools documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#declaring-dependencies) for more information.

Another option is to use [`requirements.txt`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#requirements-files) file with [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/index.html) rather than using `easy_install` as a package installer.  `pip` has now become the recommended installer; see the [Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/index.html) for more information.

Update [2015-01]: The previous version of this answer referred to the `distribute` fork of `setuptools`.  The `distribute` fork has since been merged back into a newer active `setuptools` project.  `distribute` is now dead and should no longer be used.  `setuptools` and `pip` are now very actively maintained and support Python 3.

Comment: The requires argument in distutils is unusable and unused, you have to use pip requirements files or setuptools’ install_requires argument until PEP 345 is widely used (it makes install_requires officially supported, with a new name: requires-dist; distutils2 supports it).

Comment: NB: this comment has become outdated; Distribute and setuptools have merged.  Setuptools now has full 3.x support.

Comment: @Kevin, thanks for the reminder; a lot has changed since the original answer was written.  I've updated the answer to reflect a more current state of the world: the merge back of Distribute and setuptools, the end of distutils2 development, the blessing of `pip` as the official Python package installer, and the new `Python Packaging User Guide`.

Answer (score 0):

The argument `install_requires` in setup function from distutils work for me well, only if I create sdist distributive, like: `python setup.py sdist`

Comment: `install_requires` is **not** an argument of `distutils.core.setup` it is an [extra argument in distribute - setuptools](http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/setuptools.html#new-and-changed-setup-keywords) so you need to use the distribute version of `setup` as @Ned said previously. You can also look at [this answer that describe the state of packaging modules](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14753678/965798) in python.