# "Compiling" Python to run on another machine

Tags: python, cron, pycharm

I have created a simple-medium complexity script written in Python using Pycharm on my laptop and I wish to run this on my Raspberry Pi using Crontab. All of my past programming experience has been with C++ and C# in Windows and so I would normally just do a build of the project and it all gets compiled and linked into a single executable file.

For Python how do you "compile" the script so that it can be run on another PC? I use some external libraries (requests and ImgurClient) which I had to install using the Pycharm app. I guess I'm correct in thinking that these need to be taken across to the RaspPi too? My script is in two files and so do I need to copy both of these files across? Is there a way to build them into a single file to use easily?

This is my first script which I've written just from my knowledge of other languages and a bit of Googling. Just don't know how to proceed now that I have the actual script.

Comment: No need to compile, all you need is a compatible version of Python on the target machine. After that it is as simple as copying the .py file over and running it.

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11409416/moving-a-python-script-to-another-computer

Comment: It's possible to package interpreter, script & deps into a single standalone executable even on Linux, but **you really don't want to**. This will make your program much, much slower to start up than it would have been if you'd just done things the conventional way -- that is, by copying the Python source (perhaps packaged as a Python egg or similar), installing an interpreter and any necessary library dependencies, and then using that interpreter to run the file. [The startup overhead might be tolerable on some larger machines, but on a Pi it'll be much, much, **much** too slow].

Comment: ...that's because before that single executable will actually run, it needs to *unpack* the interpreter and everything else into separate files (typically in a temporary directory), so you're gaining no runtime speed advantage (code still being interpreted!), but eating a big runtime speed disadvantage (need to unpack everything at startup!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Python installed on your Raspberry Pi, then from the shell, you just need to run:

```
# This installs pip (Python installer) as well as the requests library
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Once that is installed, run:

```
# To install the ImgurClient
pip install imgurpython
```

Then you can just run your script at the shell by typing:

```
python your_script_name.py
```

---

If you do not already have Python installed, just run the following command to install it before the others:

```
sudo apt-get install python
```

Comment: Is `requests` already packaged, or should that be added here as well?

Comment: `requests` is installed as part of the `pip` install

Comment: I'm having trouble with the `pip install imgurpython` command. I'm getting a "ImportError: cannoy import name IncompleteRead" error. Do you know what might be causing this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can "compile" python files to `.pyc` but you would still need the python interpreter on the RaspPi to run them.

On a PC that does not have Python, you can create a standalone executable using `py2exe`, but the executable must then run on Windows.

You have to install a python interpreter on your raspberry Pi, or create an executable with `py2exe` which targets raspberry Pi (if py2exe exists on that platform), that would be on another raspberry Pi :)

Another alternative would be `Cython`, but with external libraries as complex as the ones you want to use that would be a really difficult route.

[Python on Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/python)

[Creating python exes on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304883/what-do-i-use-on-linux-to-make-a-python-program-executable)

Answer (score 0):

Python does not need to compile as it is an interpretive language. You will be fine running it on another machine as long as you aren't making system calls. System calls will only become a problem if you are trying to do things like use windows commands on a linux machine.

Just copy those two files over to the pi and run like normal. Or from the terminal

```
python program.py
```

Comment: Do I not need to install the external libraries I'm using? I do 'import requests' etc and so the raspberry pi would need to know how to find this.

Comment: @TomDippé, yes, you need to install them, but you're running Debian; it has them (well, definitely `requests`) packaged.

Comment: @TomDippé if you are unsure about packages that are included you can always look in your python path. But Charles is correct in that most of the libraries will be there. The only things that might not be are extra libraries that you installed later, ie not default python libraries like numpy or scipy. Then use pip to install, apt, or something like anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

Use PyInstaller. In the terminal, to create a stand alone exe just use a command like this:

```
pyinstaller -F myscript.py
```

Comment: Not for a Raspberry Pi -- those don't run .exe files, and you *really* don't want the startup-time overhead of a PyInstaller unpack anyhow.

Comment: RaspPi is running Raspbian (based on Debian) and so can't run as an exe

Comment: @TomDippé, ...PyInstaller is not actually Windows-only -- it can create Linux executables as well -- but those Linux executables will be painfully slow to run (well, to start running) on a Pi.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers have said, you can just run your code on the Pi, because Python code is interpreted and not complied.

That being said, you will need to install any python packages, like the ImgurClient beforehand. If you did this with PyCharm on you PC, you will likely have to use [pip](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/python-pip-usage) on the Pi.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are gonna be able to run the python script in your other environment, specially if the script uses external libraries (.whl) that you normally install with pip.

A good option to run the script on a clean environment is to use virtualenv:

https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/

"It creates an environment that has its own installation directories, that doesn’t share libraries with other virtualenv environments (and optionally doesn’t access the globally installed libraries either)"

And then install only the necessary librarys to run your script. If you export this new environment, you will probably be able to run your script without any problems.