# Python 3: ImportError "No Module named Setuptools"

Tags: python, module, package, setup.py, python-3.3

I'm having troubles with installing packages in Python 3.

I have always installed packages with `setup.py install`. But now, when I try to install the ansicolors package I get:

```
importerror "No Module named Setuptools"
```

I have no idea what to do because I didn't have setuptools installed in the past. Still, I was able to install many packages with `setup.py install` without setuptools. Why should I get setuptools now?

I can't even install setuptools because I have Python 3.3 and setuptools doesn't support Python 3.

Why doesn't my install command work anymore?

Answer (score 719, accepted):

Your `setup.py` file needs `setuptools`. Some Python packages used to use `distutils` for distribution, but most now use `setuptools`, a more complete package. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344076/differences-between-distribute-distutils-and-setuptools) is a question about the differences between them.

To install `setuptools` on Debian:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
```

For an older version of Python (Python 2.x):

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
```

Comment: thanks for this post.. helped me a lot..Many peoples are advicing setuptools but its not possible to instal in py3.3..the distribute works like a charm

Comment: i had to install it with "python3" to get it work: `sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools`

Comment: On Slackware64 14.2 ?

Because i try to reintall it, and the issue persist ?

Comment: I installed `python3 python3-pip python3-setuptools` and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: For some reason in Ubuntu 18.04 it does not work with `apt-get install python3-setuptools`.

Comment: @loretoparisi I got this same problem, did you find a solution for ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: On my Linux Mint 'Tricia' Python 2.7 is the default and I successfully implemented the first solution suggested above

Comment: I used `pip3 install setuptools`.

Comment: For Alpine linux it is `py3-setuptools`.

Answer (score 198):

**EDIT:** Official [setuptools dox page](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/):

> If you have Python 2 >=2.7.9 or Python 3 >=3.4 installed from
> python.org, you will already have pip and setuptools, but will need to
> upgrade to the latest version:
>
> On Linux or OS X:
>
> ```
> pip install -U pip setuptools
> ```
>
> On Windows:
>
> ```
> python -m pip install -U pip setuptools
> ```

**Therefore the rest of this post related to *Distribute* is obsolete (e.g. some links don't work).**

#### EDIT 2022-02-04

From Python 3.10 [Distutils is deprecated and will be removed in Python 3.12](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#distutils) - use [setuptools](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/):

> The entire distutils package is deprecated, to be removed in Python 3.12. Its functionality
> for specifying package builds has already been completely replaced by
> third-party packages setuptools and packaging ...

### Distribute (deprecated)

[Distribute](http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/) - is a setuptools fork which "offers Python 3 support". Installation instructions for distribute(setuptools) + pip:

```
curl -O http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py
python distribute_setup.py
easy_install pip
```

Similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16511005/565525).

UPDATE: [Distribute](http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/) seems to be obsolete, i.e. merged into Setuptools: *Distribute is a deprecated fork of the Setuptools project. Since the Setuptools 0.7 release, Setuptools and Distribute have merged and Distribute is no longer being maintained. All ongoing effort should reference the Setuptools project and the Setuptools documentation.*

You may try with [instructions](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#unix-wget) found on setuptools pypi page (I haven't tested this, sorry :( ):

```
wget https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py -O - | python
easy_install pip
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm not sure how this solved my problem but it did. instantly! I was having serious issues trying to install distribute. this must have somehow forced the install as `sudo pip install distribute` would not work. My issues are documented at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846742/issue-with-python-path-importerror-no-module-named-setuptools?noredirect=1#comment24295110_16846742

Comment: This works cross-platform (Win), whereas the accepted answer is not applicable. Thanks!

Comment: URLS are not longer valid .. could you please check ?

Comment: This worked for me, while the accepted answer ended up in broken python distribution after installing certain packages afterwards.

Answer (score 66):

**Make sure you are running the latest version of pip**

I tried to install [Ansible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansible_(software)) and it failed with

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools_rust'

`python3-setuptools` was already in place, so upgrading `pip` solved it.

```
pip3 install -U pip
```

Comment: Solved the issue just by upgrading pip using "pip3 install -U pip 
". Thanks mate!

Comment: Of all the solutions, this is the one that worked.

Answer (score 40):

I was doing this inside a [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) on Oracle Linux 6.4 using Python 2.6, so the *apt*-based solutions weren't an option for me, nor were the Python 2.7 ideas. My fix was to upgrade my version of setuptools that had been installed by virtualenv:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

After that, I was able to install packages into the virtualenv.

Comment: Note, it had trouble "Cannot remove entries from nonexistent file..." Adding --ignore-installed to the above command fixed that.

Answer (score 36):

The solution which worked for me was to upgrade my setuptools:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```

Answer (score 32):

For others with the same issue due to a different reason: This can also happen when there's a `pyproject.toml` in the same directory as the `setup.py`, even when `setuptools` is available.

Removing `pyproject.toml` fixed the issue for me.

Comment: This just solved all my lifes problems. Can confirm this works. Thans Jan!

Comment: Because pip looks into pyproject.toml (as setup.py and other files) as project configuration place.

Comment: I am having no issues with having both config files in the projects I work with, upgrading pip and installing setuptools was enough.

Comment: THank you so much!!! Was pulling my hair out trying to debug this. Python is great but packaging makes me want to scream.

Answer (score 16):

`pip uninstall setuptools`

and then:

`pip install setuptools`

This works for me and fixes my issue.

Comment: This worked for me!  Somehow my setuptools was older version 28.8. This uninstall and reinstall forced it to update to version 48. And then everything worked fine.

Comment: In my case, two different versions of `setuptools` were installed for some reason. Discovered it when I tried `pip uninstall`

Comment: pip install --upgrade setuptools also does the trick

Comment: This works because it installs a later version of setuptools

Answer (score 13):

**First step #1**
*You have to install `setuptools`*

> On Linux:
>
> `pip install -U pip setuptools`

> On Mac OS:
>
> `pip install -U pip setuptools`

> On Windows:
>
> `python -m pip install -U pip setuptools`

**Second step #2**

*Make sure you have made it accessible (make it available in environmental variables)*

> On Linux
>
> `export PATH="INSTALLATIONDIRECTORY:$PATH"`

> On Mac OS
>
> Sorry, I don't know.

> On Windows
>
> 1. Open the Start Search, type in “env”, and choose “Edit the system environment variables”
> 2. Click the “Environment Variable” button.
> 3. Set the environment variables as needed. The New button adds an additional variable.
> 4. Dismiss all of the dialogs by choosing “OK”. Your changes are saved!

Answer (score 13):

When there's a `pyproject.toml` in the same directory as the `setup.py`, it can be the cause of the issue. I renamed that file, but it didn't solve the issue, so I restablished the original file name, and did the following change.

Under the [build-system] section, I added "setuptools" to the requires= list, and it worked.

Comment: this worked for me - i was tearing my hair out. thank you.

Answer (score 9):

this is how my problem was solved => `pip3 install setuptools-rust`

If you want to check your list => `pip3 list`

i faced this problem while trying to install elastalert2

System informations

CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)

Python 3.6.8

pip 21.3.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)

Comment: This is exactly the solution. I switched to torch_mps and in order to install transformer it requires rust to compile the `tokenizer`.

Comment: Happy to hear its working :)

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this problem when my pip requirements.txt file contained an editable library that was built using poetry and contained a pyproject.toml file.  Following the documentation for [setuptools](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/build_meta.html), my solution was to add setuptools to the build-system requirements in the pyproject.toml file as follows:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0", "setuptools"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

Answer (score 5):

The `distribute` package provides a Python 3-compatible version of `setuptools`: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute

Also, use [`pip`](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html#installing-globally) to install the modules. It automatically finds dependencies and installs them for you.

It works just fine for me with your package:

```
[~] pip --version                                                              
pip 1.2.1 from /usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages (python 3.3)
[~] sudo pip install ansicolors                                                
Downloading/unpacking ansicolors
  Downloading ansicolors-1.0.2.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package ansicolors

Installing collected packages: ansicolors
  Running setup.py install for ansicolors

Successfully installed ansicolors
Cleaning up...
[~]
```

Answer (score 4):

If `pip` isn't installed, like for example if it's coming from the [Deadsnakes PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Edeadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa), or a Docker environment, the best way to fix this error is by [bootstrapping](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html) it by running

```
python -m ensurepip
```

Answer (score 4):

I ran `sudo python setup.py build_ext -i` and it failed with `No module named setuptools`.

I solved it with this command:

```
<i>sudo apt-get install python-setuptools</i>
```

Answer (score 3):

Windows 7:

I have given a complete solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20038284/how-to-install-selenium-for-python-and-c-sharp/30542856#30542856) for Python [Selenium WebDriver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software)#Selenium_WebDriver):

1. Setup easy install (Windows - simplified)

   1. download ez.setup.py (https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py) from 'https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools'
   2. move ez.setup.py to `C:\Python27\`
   3. open cmd prompt
   4. `cd C:\Python27\`
   5. `C:\Python27\python.exe ez.setup.py install`

Answer (score 2):

A few years ago I inherited a Python (2.7.1) project running under Django-1.2.3 and now was asked to enhance it with QR possibilities. I got the same problem and did not find *pip* or *apt-get* either. So I solved it in a totally different, but easy way.

I /bin/vi-ed the setup.py and changed the line
"from setuptools import setup"
into:
"from distutils.core import setup"

Answer (score 1):

The [PyPA recommended](https://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/current.html) tool for installing and managing Python packages is `pip`. `pip` is included with Python 3.4 ([PEP 453](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0453/)), but for older versions here's [how to install](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html) it (on Windows):

Download https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

```
>c:\Python33\python.exe get-pip.py
Downloading/unpacking pip
Downloading/unpacking setuptools
Installing collected packages: pip, setuptools
Successfully installed pip setuptools
Cleaning up...

>c:\Python33\Scripts\pip.exe install pymysql
Downloading/unpacking pymysql
Installing collected packages: pymysql
Successfully installed pymysql
Cleaning up...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still find this issue, try this:

```
python3 -m pip install scrapy --upgrade --force --user
```

Answer (score 0):

While trying to install socketIO I had the same issue. At my system (Windows 11) setupTools were there twice. At `C:\Program Files\Python310\Lib\site-packages\` and at `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\`
Had to uninstall one of them.

Answer (score 0):

On macOS, if you have [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) installed, simply run:

```
brew install rust
```

Answer (score 0):

I had such a problem to install pyunicorn. I wanted to install it on Google Colab. I tried installing pyunicorn directly from Github and it worked for me. For example in my case it was like this:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/pik-copan/pyunicorn.git#egg=pyunicorn
```

Answer (score 0):

Working on Debian, sometime it can be because of older pip version. Therefore, update pip>

> python -m pip install -U pip

Answer (score -2):

If you using `poetry` to manage your virtual environment, have poetry upgrade your version of setuptools:

```bash
poetry update
```

> **Note**: Specifying `poetry update setuptools` might not work for you, since `setuptools` may not be an explicit dependency.

Answer (score -3):

Try installing the same using python==3.7.6

It worked for me.