# ImportError: No module named 'setuptools'

Tags: python, twitter

I'm new to python and have just installed the Python 3, I'm new to Python and I'm facing difficulties in importing a new library.

I'm trying to import tweepy-master library into python, I read the instructions given on their github page and did the `"python setup.py install"` command in command prompt (on windows 8), but I get the error which I've mentioned above,

Guys, please help, is there a separate library called setuptools which I need to install first?

Answer (score 9):

It seems that you should use [Setuptools](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/), i.e. [Distribute](http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/) is deprecated:

> Distribute is a deprecated fork of the Setuptools project. Since the
>   Setuptools 0.7 release, Setuptools and Distribute have merged and
>   Distribute is no longer being maintained. All ongoing effort should
>   reference the Setuptools project and the Setuptools documentation.

### Obsolete

You should use [distribute](http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/) - a setuptools fork which "offers Python 3 support".

Installation instructions (according to [documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/)):

- download python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py (link is broken, obsolete information)
- run it:   `python distribute_setup.py`

It is recommended to install [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/) too: `easy_install pip`

Comment: Link seems to be broken...

Comment: +1 for updating the answer

Comment: The distribute_setup.py link is again broken D:

Comment: Yes, thanks for noting this out. This is obsolete information, so should not be used - use Setuptools instead.