# Installing MySQL Python (on Windows 7)

Tags: python, mysql, windows

I was trying to install MySQL-python 1.2.3 for Python2.7. I am using windows 7. I have added python to path variable and I tried the following: `python setup.py install`
But I get an error:

```
Traceback <most recent call last>:
From "setup.py", line 5, in <module>
from setuptools import setup, Extension
ImportError: No module named setuptools
```

Comment: Read the following post to have your query answered - 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426491/python-3-importerror-no-module-named-setuptools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install it from [this location](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/), which is a repository of compiled Windows libraries for Python.

You should also install `setuptools` (from that same location).