# Pygame for Python 3 - "Setup.py build" command error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am following these directions: http://www.pygame.org/wiki/CompileUbuntu?parent=Compilation

The instructions give the steps in installing Pygame for Python 3 on Ubuntu.

I am having no problems with it until i reach the `python3 setup.py build` step. This is what the command outputs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 109, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup, find_packages
ImportError: No module named 'setuptools'
```

If i simply run `import pygame` in both Python 2 and Python 3, it reports that there is no module called pygame.

Is there anything special that is needed to be done? Thanks!

**EDIT:** Followed @docmarvin 's directions and installed the module setuptools. Still the same error

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment? If not, why not? You have to have setuptools installed.

Comment: No, I have Ubuntu 16.04 installed on my computer

Comment: Not a virtual machine, a [virtual environment](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/)

Comment: As far as I know, I am not using a virtual environment, unless one was installed by default. @Two-BitAlchemist I checked to see if there's a command i can run to verify that I'm not running any, but didn't find any.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3: ImportError "No Module named Setuptools"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426491/python-3-importerror-no-module-named-setuptools)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo apt install python3-setuptools
                       ^ separate from Python 2 setuptools.
```

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14426553/2877364).

Comment: It works. Didn't find the other answer before. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try to install setuptools, e.g. with pip from the command line:
`pip install setuptools`

Comment: I installed pip itself using `sudo apt install python-pip` .  I then did the `pip install setuptools` and it says that it was successfully installed. However when i run the `python3 setup.py build`, it is still saying there is no module named setuptools

Comment: I'm not using python3. Maybe you have to call `pip3 install setuptools` there? Your `pip ...` call might have installed setuptools for the python2 environment installed as well.