# Problems with Python: ImportError: No module named ... [Linux]

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, ubuntu, python-module

I am a noob with installing python programs. I know there are a lot of Questions like this here, I have tried to find a solution for my problem but I can't fix it.
First of all, I am trying to install a program called [Qarq](https://github.com/linkedin/qark). The readme says:

```
Setup

In order to get qark running, it must be present on your python path. If not, it may lead to module not found errors. This can be done for your current shell by running the following:

export PYTHONPATH={qark root directory}:$PYTHONPATH
```

Well, I type the command. I check the variable with an echo and I can see the directory in the variable. However, I type "python setup.py install" and I get this error:

```
  santoku@santoku-PC:~/qark$ python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 1, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup, find_packages
ImportError: No module named setuptools
```

Then, I read in a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426491/python-3-importerror-no-module-named-setuptools) that you must install setuptools, so I did it. I ran the next command:

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
```

But the problem is still there, I try to run "python setup.py install" and I get the same error.
On the other hand, the readme says you only need to execute "$ python qarkMain.py". I do that and I get the same error with different module:

```
santoku@santoku-PC:~/qark/qark$ python qarkMain.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "qarkMain.py", line 30, in <module>
    from qark.modules.IssueType import IssueSeverity
ImportError: No module named qark.modules.IssueType
```

I am using Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 12 2016, 01:02:22) [GCC 4.8.4] on linux2. (Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS)
I have tried to install qark on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS and it worked perfectly. I didn't need to install setuptools. Both have the same python version.
I guess the problem is python can't find the modules, maybe I have to move the qark directory to another directory.
I think that's all, if you need more extra information just ask me.
I need your help, I am sure my problem is a foolishness and easy to fix. But I am a noob with python and I don't have any idea.
Thank you very much and thanks in advance.
Sorry for my English, I am not a native speaker.

EDIT: I found a solution, I tried to install again the OS and now python works properly, I don't know if I broke python or I did something bad. Anyway, Thanks.

Comment: What does echo $PYTHONPATH say?

Comment: It says {/home/santoku/qark/qark}:{/home/santoku/qark}:, I think it should be with more directories...cuz if I don't add this directories manually it would be empty. But I don't know how it works...

Comment: Is that {} literally present? I think it should ideally be `export PYTHONPATH=/home/santoku/qark/qark:/home/santoku/qark`. See if that helps.

Comment: Yes, I've already tried that and it doesn't work. I get the same result. Well, note exactly the same, now If I try to install qarkMain.py I get this: ImportError: No module named _curses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i could get it work typing this:

1) `PYTHONPATH=\home\santoku\qark\qark\:$PYTHONPATH`

then just type:

2) `python qarkMain.py`