# No module named setuptools.dist

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I wanted to install `Basemap Matplotlib` Toolkit from [here](https://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/installing.html)

But during installation with this command:

`python setup.py install`

I got this **Error**:
`No module named setuptools.dist`

But I have `setutools module` in my `ubuntu 20.04`.

And I don't know what's the problem.
Is there anybody who can help me?

Comment: Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426491/python-3-importerror-no-module-named-setuptools) solution.

Comment: Dear @Luke Isaid that in my question that I have installed setuptools but still doesn't help