# Python Module Installation ModuleNotFoundError Error

Tags: python, terminal

Recently, I am trying to install PyDictionary on my IDE (I am using Mac). However, when I typed "pip3 install PyDictionary" to my terminal, an error occurred as in the following picture.

[image: Error].

I also tried to install setuptools by typing in "pip3 install setuptools", but it showed that the requirement is already satisfied. Nevertheless, according to my terminal, it said "No module named 'setuptools'", which to me, is contradicting. Sorry if this is a silly question since I am only a middle school student.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 3: ImportError "No Module named Setuptools"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426491/python-3-importerror-no-module-named-setuptools)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this might be late.

1. Check Version: Make sure you're using the correct Python version. There could be multiple Python installations if you are not careful sometimes, and you need to make sure you're using the one where setuptools is installed.
2. Update pip: Make sure that your pip is updated by running `pip3 install --upgrade pip`
3. Permissions: Try running the installation with `sudo pip3 install PyDictionary`. If pip3 does not work.
4. Dependencies: Make sure there are no conflicting dependencies/libraries/packages in your system.

Comment: did you use any generative AI at all in the writing of this answer post?

Answer (score 1):

you can verify the installation of the PyDictionary by using:

> pip list

and the meaning of "requirement is already satisfied" is that the setuptools is already installed.

Comment: Yeah thanks, but what I am trying to ask is why does it say "No module named 'setuptools'" if I already have it installed?