# ERROR: 'python3 setup.py build ' execution failed. in yocto dunfell

Tags: python-3.7, yocto, setuptools, meson-build

I am trying to build core-image-minimal(rootfs) using yocto. yocto version :3.1.17"

Am using Poky dunfell branch. trying to build Local image with python3
but getting bellow issue:

Log data follows:

```
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile

| Traceback (most recent call last):

|   File "/home/ubuntu/project/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/meson-
native/0.53.2-r0/meson-0.53.2/setup.py", line 24, in <module>

|     from setuptools import setup

| **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'**

| ERROR: 'python3 setup.py build ' execution failed.

| WARNING: /home/ubuntu/project/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/meson-native/0.53.2-r0/temp/run.do_compile.33462:1 exit 1 from 'exit 1'

| ERROR: Execution of '/home/ubuntu/project/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/meson-native/0.53.2-r0/temp/run.do_compile.33462' failed with exit code 1
```

what may be root cause ?

I can see setup.py trying to import setuptools, but not finding it. also we have included python3-setuptools as dependency.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 3: ImportError "No Module named Setuptools"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426491/python-3-importerror-no-module-named-setuptools)

Comment: **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'** : is the error . which says the package i am trying to build couldn't find find setuptools. but the package recipe is  built as dependency

Comment: If I am getting the idea right, you have a recipe that will provide a python package and it can't find `setuptools`? If that is the case, can you provide the recipe content ?