# ImportError: No module named setuptools on Raspbian OS

Tags: raspbian, raspberry-pi4, adafruit, adafruit-circuitpython

I tried to install the Adafruit Python DTH on my Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W (Raspbian64 OS) [according to this tutorial](https://www.circuitbasics.com/how-to-set-up-the-dht11-humidity-sensor-on-the-raspberry-pi/) - see section PROGRAMMING THE DHT11 WITH PYTHON

For the last step `sudo python setup.py install` I get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 1, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup, find_packages, Extension
ImportError: No module named setuptools
```

I then also installed setuptools which looked successful, but above message keep displaying. After installation of setuptools I could not call any command like `setuptools`..

Anybody here with similar experience or has already a solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426491/python-3-importerror-no-module-named-setuptools

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would try is to install `setuptools` using `apt` (which is the system package manager):

```bash
sudo apt install python3-setuptools
```

If this didn't work you can use the method described in [this](https://www.stuffaboutcode.com/2012/10/raspberry-pi-python-installing-modules.html?m=1) blog post from 2012 about Raspberry Pi:

```bash
mkdir python-setuptools
cd python-setuptools
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -O - | sudo python
```

Then download whatever module you need and run the setup.py program using the command:

```bash
sudo python setup.py install
```