# Installing trepan debugger for Python 3 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.x, trepan

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with Python version 2.7.6. I recently installed Python version 3.4.2 side-by-side with the system Python using `pyenv`. Now I would like to test out some debuggers for Python 3, and I downloaded `trepan-0.2.8-py3.3.egg` from the [python3-trepan project page](https://code.google.com/p/python3-trepan/).

Then I ran `pyenv global 3.4.2` and `easy_install trepan-0.2.8-py3.3.egg`, which gave me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/bin/easy_install", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1909, in main
    with_ei_usage(lambda:
  File "/home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1896, in with_ei_usage
    return f()
  File "/home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1913, in <lambda>
    distclass=DistributionWithoutHelpCommands, **kw
  File "/home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 358, in run
    self.easy_install(spec, not self.no_deps)
  File "/home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 574, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(None, spec, tmpdir, deps, True)
  File "/home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 625, in install_item
    self.process_distribution(spec, dist, deps)
  File "/home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 671, in process_distribution
    [requirement], self.local_index, self.easy_install
  File "/home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 564, in resolve
    dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, self, installer)
  File "/home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 802, in best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer) # try and download/install
  File "/home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 814, in obtain
    return installer(requirement)
  File "/home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 593, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "/home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 623, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "/home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 809, in install_eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "/home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1015, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "/home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1000, in run_setup
    run_setup(setup_script, args)
  File "/home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 50, in run_setup
    lambda: execfile(
  File "/home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 100, in run
    return func()
  File "/home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 52, in <lambda>
    {'__file__':setup_script, '__name__':'__main__'}
  File "/home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/compat.py", line 78, in execfile
    exec(compile(source, fn, 'exec'), globs, locs)
  File "setup.py", line 12, in <module>
ImportError: No module named '__pkginfo__'
```

**Update:**

The problem seems not to be related to installing Python 3 using `pyenv`: I tried the following:

- disabled `pyenv`
- `sudo apt-get install python3 python`
- `sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools`
- `sudo easy_install-3.4 trepan-0.2.8-py3.3.egg`

This gave me the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/easy_install-3.4", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('setuptools==3.3', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install-3.4')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1963, in main
    with_ei_usage(lambda:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1950, in with_ei_usage
    return f()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1967, in <lambda>
    distclass=DistributionWithoutHelpCommands, **kw
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 381, in run
    self.easy_install(spec, not self.no_deps)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 597, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(None, spec, tmpdir, deps, True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 648, in install_item
    self.process_distribution(spec, dist, deps)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 694, in process_distribution
    [requirement], self.local_index, self.easy_install
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 620, in resolve
    dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 858, in best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer) # try and download/install
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 870, in obtain
    return installer(requirement)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 616, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 646, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 834, in install_eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1040, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1025, in run_setup
    run_setup(setup_script, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 50, in run_setup
    lambda: execfile(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 100, in run
    return func()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 52, in <lambda>
    {'__file__':setup_script, '__name__':'__main__'}
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/compat.py", line 78, in execfile
    exec(compile(source, fn, 'exec'), globs, locs)
  File "setup.py", line 12, in <module>
ImportError: No module named '__pkginfo__'
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it, but the maintainer @rocky recommends this to install:

```
pip3 install trepan3k
```

**OLD**:

Install using this command:

```
pip3 install -e git+https://github.com/rocky/python3-trepan/#egg=trepan
```

I think the current tarball/eggs are broken

Comment: Because of the problems with pip and python3 I've also added `trepan3k` as its own pip. So a `pip install trepan3k` should also work now.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with trepan 0.4.2 (at this writing we are at 0.4.7), the pip problems were addressed. However...

You are using pyenv but note that on Ubuntu 14.04 without that, you may need to use *pip3* instead of *pip*.  Outside of pyenv I think defaults *pip* to Python2's *pip*. See also [this link](http://this%20link).

And alas, there is another weirdness. When a wheel is not available (as was the case before version 0.4.7), pip uses the source tarball to install from rather than an egg. However the source code for Python 2 versus Python 3 is necessarily different and it would be too difficult to try to combine these into one source.

So, I have started to put wheel format file on pypi.org and I hope this too will address problems like this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/95037/what-is-the-best-way-to-install-python-packages or https://askubuntu.com/questions/350437/installing-python-modules-on-ubuntu or [Installing python modules on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19034959/installing-python-modules-on-ubuntu)

This just might solve the problem. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I should not have installed Python 3 using `pyenv install 3.4.2` and used `sudo apt-get install python3` instead?

Comment: I think my previous comment is not the case.. see discussion in updated question.