# How to install python smtplib module in ubuntu os

Tags: python, module, smtplib

I tried to install python module via pip, but it was not successful. 
can any one help me to install smtplib python module in ubuntu 12.10 OS?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19034959/installing-python-modules-on-ubuntu

Comment: smtplib is installed by default. You do not need to install it. The module is part of the default python package.

Answer (score 33):

`smptlib` is part of [python's standard library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/), so you do not have to install it.

Answer (score 8):

I will tell you a probable why you might be getting error like Error no module smtplib

I had created program as email.py

Now email is a module in python and because of that it start giving error for smtplib also

then I had to delete email.pyc file created and then rename email.py to mymail.py

After that no error of smtplib

Make sure your file name is not conflicting with the python module. Also see because of that any *.pyc file created inside the folder

Answer (score 3):

you can install smtplib using the command below it helped me to solve the error
install using pip

```
pip install secure-smtplib
```

Answer (score -2):

For Linux based distro, it is easy to install from source. Just download the source code from [here](https://pypi.org/project/secure-smtplib/#files), extract it and open in a terminal.
Now `sudo python3 setup.py install`
Installation should be complete in seconds