# How to install csvformat in linux?

Tags: python, linux, csv, ubuntu

I was working before on Raspberry Pi, but once I moved to an Ubuntu PC, the code below is not working anymore. I guess I need to somehow install that csvformat, but not sure how.

Python code:

```py
import os
import subprocess
import pandas
import pandas as pd

subprocess.call("csvformat -t plates.txt >> plates.csv", shell=True)

f=pd.read_csv("plates.csv")

keep_col = [11,13]
new_f = f[keep_col]
new_f.to_csv("new_plates.csv", index=False)

subprocess.call("sudo rm plates.csv", shell=True)

df = pd.read_csv("new_plates.csv", names=["Plates", "Name"])
df["Plates"] = df["Plates"].str.split().apply("".join)

print(df)
```

Error message:

```
/bin/sh: 1: csvformat: not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 14, in <module>
    new_f = f[keep_col]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2934, in __getitem__
    raise_missing=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1354, in _convert_to_indexer
    return self._get_listlike_indexer(obj, axis, **kwargs)[1]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1161, in _get_listlike_indexer
    raise_missing=raise_missing)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1246, in _validate_read_indexer
    key=key, axis=self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)))
KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([11, 13], dtype='int64')] are in the [columns]
```

Comment: if you have to install something on Ubuntu then first check `apt search ...` - like `apt search csvkit` - and later you can use `apt install ...`

Comment: As an aside, [you want to avoid `shell=True`](/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess); `with open('plates.csv', 'a') as out: subprocess.call(["csvformat","-t", "plates.txt"], stdout=out, shell=False)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19034959/installing-python-modules-on-ubuntu

Comment: Your title and question description is misleading because you have 2 different, unrelated problems. 1 is the "_csvformat: not found_" error and 1 is the "_KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([11, 13], dtype='int64')] are in the [columns]_" error. I've updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56990373/2745495) to try to address both.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 different, unrelated problems.

#### 1st problem:

```
/bin/sh: 1: csvformat: not found
```

Your script seems to be looking for the [`csvformat`](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripts/csvformat.html) command line tool which is part [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

You can [install csvkit with pip](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/1_getting_started.html#installing-csvkit):

> #### 1.2. Installing csvkit
>
> Installing csvkit is easy:
>
> ```
> sudo pip install csvkit
> ```
>
> Note:
>
> If you’re familiar with [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), it is better to install csvkit in
>   its own environment. If you are doing this, then you should leave off
>   the `sudo` in the previous command.

As noted in the csvkit documentation (and in the comments), doing `sudo pip install` is generally considered as bad. See [What are the risks of running 'sudo pip'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21055859/2745495). Using a virtual environment is the recommended approach.

After installing csvkit, check that you now have csvformat:

```
csvformat -h
```

Now, when you run your script, make sure that the `pip` you used to install csvkit is **the same Python** (`python`, `python3`, ..) that you use to run your script. For example, if you use `python` to run your script:

```
$ python -m pip list | grep csvkit
csvkit          1.0.4
```

If `csvkit` does not appear, then you installed it somewhere else.

### 2nd problem:

```
KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([11, 13], dtype='int64')] are in the [columns]
```

You are getting this because you are accessing (slicing) the contents of `f` incorrectly. The return of [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) is a pandas DataFrame. You can't just use `f[11,13]` to slice it. You need to use either [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html?highlight=loc#pandas.DataFrame.loc) (label-based slicing) or [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html?highlight=iloc#pandas.DataFrame.iloc) (integer indexing-based slicing).

I don't know what you are actually trying to do with `keep_col = [11,13]`, but you should do something like this instead:

```
f=pd.read_csv("test.csv")
#     1  ..  11  12  13  ..
# 0   x  ..  x   x   x   ..
# 1   x  ..  x   x   x   ..
# 2   x  ..  x   x   x   ..
# ..

f_slice_1 = f.loc[:, '11':'13']
#     11  12  13 
# 0   x   x   x  
# 1   x   x   x  
# 2   x   x   x   
# ..

f_slice_2 = f.iloc[:, 11:13]
#     12  13 
# 0   x   x  
# 1   x   x  
# 2   x   x 
# ..
```

Comment: Installing it via sudo is dangerous, as it can overwrite any version installed via the distributions package manager. Either without sudo (installing specific to the user) or in a virtualenv is the preferred way.