# Python Packaging Documentation

Tags: python, package, pip, easy-install, egg

Where is the current reference for packaging python modules with Python 2.x?

- http://guide.python-distribute.org/ The Hitchhiker’s Guide to Packaging (last update from july 2010)
- http://docs.python.org/2.7/distutils/index.html distutils: Distributing Python Modules
- https://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ Python Packaging User Guide (fork of hitchhiker guide, alive)

I found the above versions. Which one should I follow?

My modules are simple. Some Python files, some Python scripts and some templates (django).

## Update 2021

I am very happy. Finding the maintained tutorial is clear today:

**https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/**

Comment: To get an idea of what's coming in future releases, you might want to read PEP 453 and this article:  http://lwn.net/Articles/570471/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**setuptools**](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/) documentation is (probably) the reference you want.

[The Hitchhiker’s Guide to Packaging](http://guide.python-distribute.org/) and 
[the Python Packaging User Guide](https://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) are both community written guides to Python packaging, but may be helpful.

You may also find [Differences between distribute, distutils, setuptools and distutils2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344076/differences-between-distribute-distutils-setuptools-and-distutils2) useful, as there are multiple packaging tools for Python (the short answer is that for Python 2, you should probably use setuptools).

Comment: The last update to the hitchhiker's guide is from july 2010. The Python Packaging User Guide is a fork, and is still alive.