# how to use setup function to create a distribution?

Tags: python, installation

I'm a Python newcomer, and I'm trying to create a distribution, just for practice at this point. I'm using Windows 10. I have done the following: I created a simple function called simple_func() and saved in as simple_func.py in a directory called simple_func. Next I try to use the setup() function to create metadata in the same directory

```
from distutils.core import setup
setup(
name = 'simple_func',
version = '1.0.0',
author = 'me',
description= 'A simple function',
)
```

After I execute this, I expect to find two files in my simple_func folder: The original file and a file of metadata, but all I have is the original code module. What stupid mistake am I making?

Comment: You may want to check http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/1381/creating-python-packages#t=201702120003441306846 and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19116138/python-packaging-documentation

Comment: Thanks. I think my whole question was a bit confused. I understand better now. The road from System/360 systems programming to the 21st century is not always easy!