# python module import - relative paths issue

Tags: python, module

I'm developing my own module in python 2.7. It resides in `~/Development/.../myModule` instead of `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` or `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages`. The internal structure is:

```
/project-root-dir
  /server
    __init__.py
    service.py
    http.py
  /client
    __init__.py
    client.py
```

`client/client.py` includes `PyCachedClient` class. I'm having import problems:

```
project-root-dir$ python
Python 2.7.2+ (default, Jul 20 2012, 22:12:53) 
[GCC 4.6.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from server import http
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "server/http.py", line 9, in <module>
    from client import PyCachedClient
ImportError: cannot import name PyCachedClient
```

I didn't set PythonPath to include my `project-root-dir`, therefore when server.http tries to include client.PyCachedClient, it tries to load it from relative path and fails. My question is - how should I set all paths/settings in a good, pythonic way? I know I can run `export PYTHONPATH=...` in shell each time I open a console and try to run my server, but I guess it's not the best way. If my module was installed via PyPi (or something similar), I'd have it installed in `/usr/lib/python...` path and it'd be loaded automatically.

I'd appreciate tips on best practices in python module development.

Comment: Very short answer: Use `virtualenv` for isolation, `setuptools` for creating a installable package and manage dependencies, and `python setup.py develop` to install that package in development mode. I'm currently writing up an answer, trying to give an example on how to put these concepts together. Oh - and *don't* use relative imports, you rarely every need to.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

## My Python development workflow

This is a basic process to develop Python packages that incorporates what I believe to be the best practices in the community. It's basic - if you're really serious about developing Python packages, there still a bit more to it, and everyone has their own preferences, but it should serve as a template to get started and then learn more about the pieces involved. The basic steps are:

- Use [`virtualenv`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) for isolation
- [`setuptools`](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/) for creating a installable package and manage dependencies
- `python setup.py develop` to install that package in development mode

### virtualenv

First, I would recommend using [`virtualenv`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) to get an isolated environment to develop your package(s) in. During development, you will need to install, upgrade, downgrade and uninstall dependencies of your package, and you don't want

- your development dependencies to pollute your system-wide `site-packages`
- your system-wide `site-packages` to influence your development environment
- version conflicts

Polluting your system-wide `site-packages` is bad, because any package you install there will be available to all Python applications you installed that use the system Python, even though you just needed that dependency for your small project. And it was just installed in a new version that overrode the one in the system wide `site-packages`, and is incompatible with ${important_app} that depends on it. You get the idea.

Having your system wide `site-packages` influence your development environment is bad, because maybe your project depends on a module you already got in the system Python's `site-packages`. So you forget to properly declare that your project depends on that module, but everything works because it's always there on your local development box. Until you release your package and people try to install it, or push it to production, etc... Developing in a clean environment forces you to properly declare your dependencies.

So, a **virtualenv** is an isolated environment with its own Python interpreter and module search path. It's based on a Python installation you previously installed, but isolated from it.

To create a virtualenv, install the `virtualenv` package by installing it to your system wide Python using `easy_install` or `pip`:

```sh
sudo pip install virtualenv
```

Notice this will be the *only* time you install something as root (using sudo), into your global site-packages. Everything after this will happen inside the virtualenv you're about to create.

Now create a virtualenv for developing your package:

```sh
cd ~/pyprojects
virtualenv --no-site-packages foobar-env
```

This will create a directory tree `~/pyprojects/foobar-env`, which is your virtualenv.

To activate the virtualenv, `cd` into it and `source` the `bin/activate script`:

```sh
~/pyprojects $ cd foobar-env/
~/pyprojects/foobar-env $ . bin/activate
(foobar-env) ~/pyprojects/foobar-env $
```

Note the leading dot `.`, that's shorthand for the `source` shell command. Also note how the prompt changes: `(foobar-env)` means your inside the activated virtualenv (and always will need to be for the isolation to work). So activate your env every time you open a new terminal tab or SSH session etc..

If you now run `python` in that activated env, it will actually use `~/pyprojects/foobar-env/bin/python` as the interpreter, with its own `site-packages` and isolated module search path.

### A setuptools package

Now for creating your package. Basically you'll want a `setuptools` package with a `setup.py` to properly declare your package's metadata and dependencies. You can do this on your own by by following the [setuptools documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/setuptools.html), or create a package skeletion using [Paster templates](http://pythonpaste.org/script/developer.html). To use Paster templates, install `PasteScript` into your virtualenv:

```sh
pip install PasteScript
```

Let's create a source directory for our new package to keep things organized (maybe you'll want to split up your project into several packages, or later use dependencies from source):

```sh
mkdir src
cd src/
```

Now for creating your package, do

```sh
paster create -t basic_package foobar
```

and answer all the questions in the interactive interface. Most are optional and can simply be left at the default by pressing ENTER.

This will create a package (or more precisely, a setuptools distribution) called `foobar`. This is the name that

- people will use to install your package using `easy_install` or `pip install foobar`
- the name other packages will use to depend on yours in `setup.py`
- what it will be called on [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi)

Inside, you almost always create a Python package (as in "a directory with an `__init__.py`) that's called the same. That's not required, the name of the top level Python package can be any valid package name, but it's a common convention to name it the same as the distribution. And that's why it's important, but not always easy, to keep the two apart. Because the top level python package name is what

- people (or you) will use to import your package using `import foobar` or `from foobar import baz`

So if you used the paster template, it will already have created that directory for you:

```sh
cd foobar/foobar/
```

Now create your code:

```sh
vim models.py
```

**`models.py`**

```py
class Page(object):
    """A dumb object wrapping a webpage.
    """

    def __init__(self, content, url):
        self.content = content
        self.original_url = url

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Page retrieved from '%s' (%s bytes)>" % (self.original_url, len(self.content))
```

And a `client.py` in the same directory that uses `models.py`:

**`client.py`**

```py
import requests
from foobar.models import Page

url = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com'

response = requests.get(url)
page = Page(response.content, url)

print page
```

Declare the dependency on the `requests` module in `setup.py`:

```py
  install_requires=[
      # -*- Extra requirements: -*-
      'setuptools',
      'requests',
  ],
```

### Version control

`src/foobar/` is the directory you'll now want to put under version control:

```sh
cd src/foobar/
git init
vim .gitignore
```

**`.gitignore`**

```
*.egg-info
*.py[co]
```

```sh
git add .
git commit -m 'Create initial package structure.
```

### Installing your package as a development egg

Now it's time to install your package in development mode:

```sh
python setup.py develop
```

This will install the `requests` dependency and *your* package as a development egg. So it's linked into your virtualenv's site-packages, but still lives at `src/foobar` where you can make changes and have them be immediately active in the virtualenv without re-installing your package.

Now for your original question, importing using relative paths: My advice is, don't do it. Now that you've got a proper setuptools package, that's installed and importable, your current working directory shouldn't matter any more. Just do `from foobar.models import Page` or similar, declaring the fully qualified name where that object lives. That makes your source code much more readable and discoverable, for yourself and other people that read your code.

You can now run your code by doing `python client.py` from anywhere inside your activated virtualenv. `python src/foobar/foobar/client.py` works just as fine, your package is properly installed and your working directory doesn't matter any more.

If you want to go one step further, you can even create a setuptools entry point for your CLI scripts. This will create a `bin/something` script in your virtualenv that you can run from the shell.

### setuptools console_scripts entry point

**`setup.py`**

```py
  entry_points='''
  # -*- Entry points: -*-    
  [console_scripts]
  run-fooobar = foobar.main:run_foobar
  ''',
```

**`client.py`**

```py
def run_client():
    # ...
```

**`main.py`**

```py
from foobar.client import run_client

def run_foobar():
    run_client()
```

Re-install your package to activate the entry point:

```sh
python setup.py develop
```

And there you go, `bin/run-foo`.

Once you (or someone else) installs your package for real, outside the virtualenv, the entry point will be in `/usr/local/bin/run-foo` or somewhere simiar, where it will automatically be in `$PATH`.

### Further steps

- Creating a release of your package and uploading it PyPi, for example using [`zest.releaser`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zest.releaser)
- Keeping a changelog and versioning your package
- Learn about [declaring dependencies](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#declaring-dependencies)
- Learn about [Differences between distribute, distutils, setuptools and distutils2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344076/differences-between-distribute-distutils-setuptools-and-distutils2)

Suggested reading:

- [The Hitchhiker’s Guide to Packaging](https://the-hitchhikers-guide-to-packaging.readthedocs.org)
- [The pip cookbook](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/cookbook.html)

Comment: I love this post... didn't expect to receive such answer :) thanks

Comment: You're welcome. I hope I didn't mess up any paths and it works as sort of a HOWTO. I left out some things to keep the post from getting even more lengthy than it already is, so feel free to ask if something's not clear enough.

Comment: I try not to leave comments like this but... this is incredibly helpful. THANK YOU.

Comment: Very very helpful answer. It convinced me that the setuptools variant is the best option combined with virtualenvs. No need for any relative import hacks. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of `python setup.py develop` you can also use `pip install -e .` when you are in the project directory.

Answer (score 2):

So, you have two *packages*, the first with modules named:

```
server         # server/__init__.py
server.service # server/service.py
server.http    # server/http.py
```

The second with modules names:

```
client         # client/__init__.py
client.client  # client/client.py
```

If you want to assume both packages are in you import path (`sys.path`), and the class you want is in `client/client.py`, then in you server you have to do:

```
from client.client import PyCachedClient
```

You asked for a symbol out of `client`, not `client.client`, and from your description, that isn't where that symbol is defined.

I personally would consider making this one package (ie, putting an `__init__.py` in the folder one level up, and giving it a suitable python package name), and having `client` and `server` be sub-packages of that package.  Then (a) you could do relative imports if you wanted to (`from ...client.client import something`), and (b) your project would be more suitable for redistribution, not putting two very generic package names at the top level of the python module hierarchy.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. Well, the server is written in python and the clients are written in python. javascript and php. That's why I separated client dir from server dir. Do you think it's a good solution?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to accomplish.  If you're writing an application, then organizing your code however it makes the best sense to you is probably preferable.  If you're writing a library, a package to put perhaps on PyPI and for others to install, then I think having your entire library contained within one enclosing package is far preferable.