# How to move repeated code into helper file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two Python scripts

- `2011/2/dinner/dinner.py`
- `2014/qualification/cookie-clicker-alpha/cookie-clicker-alpha.py`

They both define identical functions `binary_search`. For maintainability, I would like to move that function to a new file

- `helpers/binary_search.py`

Then import it from `dinner.py` and `cookie-clicker-alpha.py`. How can I do that? I am using Python 3.x .

Finally, it's important to me that `python dinner.py` still works out the box for anyone who clones my code:

```
git clone https://github.com/hickford/codejam.git
cd codejam
cd 2011/2/dinner
python dinner.py sample.in
```

Comment: Is the directory in which `binary_search.py` resides in `sys.path`?

Comment: Nope. I could put that in the readme, but I think it would be better if people could run the code out the (git clone) box without having to edit their environment variables.

Comment: If you care about other people downloading and installing your code, you'll ultimately want to create an egg-based `setuptools` distribution, and release versions of it to [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi). I outlined the basic process I use in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876993/python-module-import-relative-paths-issue), this might be helpful for you as a starting point.

Comment: or maybe try moving on to python [wheels](http://pythonwheels.com/) which is the new standard!

Comment: Typically you put `__init__.py` in the intermediate directories, I thought. So you are missing several `__init__.py`s.

Comment: Incidentally, Python has a binary search implementation in the standard library; it's in the `bisect` module.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest solution would be to make a symbolic link `helpers/binary_search.py` in both `2011/2/dinner/` and `2014/qualification/cookie-clicker-alpha/`. Then scripts in both directories can just `import binary_search`.

Another trick to make a couple of modules into one "script" is to zip them;

```
cd 2011/2/dinner
mkdir tmp
cd tmp
cp ../dinner.py __main__.py
cp ../../../helpers/binary_search.py .
zip ../foo.zip *.py
cd ..
echo '#!/usr/bin/env python' >dinner
cat foo.zip >>dinner
chmod a+x dinner
rm -rf foo.zip tmp/
```

When the "dinner" program is run, it will unpack the zipped modules and run `__main__.py`. I've used this with python2, but not with python3.