# Python module development workflow - setup and build

Tags: python, package, workflow, distribution

I'm writing my first Python module, and I'm wondering about logistics: specifically, how people deal with setup/build.

Is it standard practice to start out with all of the `distutils` stuff in place, and in a `virtualenv` to run `setup.py` for each modification and test etc?

Do people more often create a working code, then afterwards worry about converting it to a distributable package?

Very specific *example* issue: my code needs to access a data file.  Should I just hardcode in the file address, i.e. `DATA_FILE_PATH = "./data/DATA.npz"` or should I figure out how to use all of this `MANIFEST.in` / `setup(..., package_data={ ... }, ...)` stuff from the start?

---

Edit: This [**amazing** answer by @LukasGraf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19877478/230468) gives some fantastic workflow information which largely answers my questions.  Please go give him some upvotes!