# Import error with virtualenv Python but iPython works fine

Tags: python, ipython, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I am using virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper on a Mac OS X machine. My project layout is:

```
/Users/mrafayaleem/Projects/imagemonster/ (project dir)
    |---- imagemonster/
        |---- server.py
        |---- conf/
            |---- settings.py
```

I am getting Import error on the following line in server.py:

```
from imagemonster.conf import settings
```

when I run it using `python imagemonster/server.py` from the project directory.
Running it under `ipyhton` works just fine and I can't understand why this is happening.

Following are sys.paths for both:

**Python:**

```
/Users/mrafayaleem/.virtualenvs/imagemonster/lib/python27.zip
/Users/mrafayaleem/.virtualenvs/imagemonster/lib/python2.7
/Users/mrafayaleem/.virtualenvs/imagemonster/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
/Users/mrafayaleem/.virtualenvs/imagemonster/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
/Users/mrafayaleem/.virtualenvs/imagemonster/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/Users/mrafayaleem/.virtualenvs/imagemonster/Extras/lib/python
/Users/mrafayaleem/.virtualenvs/imagemonster/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/Users/mrafayaleem/.virtualenvs/imagemonster/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/Users/mrafayaleem/.virtualenvs/imagemonster/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/Users/mrafayaleem/.virtualenvs/imagemonster/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

**iPython:**

```
/Users/mrafayaleem/.virtualenvs/imagemonster/bin
/Users/mrafayaleem/.virtualenvs/imagemonster/lib/python27.zip
/Users/mrafayaleem/.virtualenvs/imagemonster/lib/python2.7
/Users/mrafayaleem/.virtualenvs/imagemonster/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
/Users/mrafayaleem/.virtualenvs/imagemonster/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
/Users/mrafayaleem/.virtualenvs/imagemonster/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/Users/mrafayaleem/.virtualenvs/imagemonster/Extras/lib/python
/Users/mrafayaleem/.virtualenvs/imagemonster/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/Users/mrafayaleem/.virtualenvs/imagemonster/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/Users/mrafayaleem/.virtualenvs/imagemonster/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/Users/mrafayaleem/.virtualenvs/imagemonster/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/Users/mrafayaleem/.virtualenvs/imagemonster/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions
/Users/mrafayaleem/.ipython
```

Can anyone please help me resolve this weird behaviour?

Comment: Do you have a file called __ init __.py in your inner imagemonster directory? (Remove the spaces, just adding those so SO doesn't interpret underlines as formatting)

Comment: @dylrei Yes! For sure!

Comment: Running `python imagemonster/server.py` will treat it as a script, not a module, so it won't see it as being inside a package. `python -m imagemonster.server` might work.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't due to virtualenv.
It's because of differences between python and IPython. IPython *also* imports from the current working directory as well as searching in the PATHs. There's a similar answer in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514593/importerror-no-module-named-when-trying-to-run-python-script).

You should `cd` into the imagemonster directory, don't `workon` virtualenv, and try:

```
python server.py
```

And deal with the import error that throws.

Answer (score 0):

Coming a little too late but this might help others looking for a solution. Ipython uses both your current system path and your current project directory but when running in a virtualenv, only the current PYTHONPATH specified during installation will be used. You have to append your current working directory to your module import declarations:

This is what I would do:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/Users/mrafayaleem/Projects/imagemonster/conf')

from imagemonster.conf import settings
```

The solution here gives a more precise solution especially when working in virtualenv  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876993/python-module-import-relative-paths-issue