# Failed to load libGL.so when running Flask app on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I'm trying to run my Flask application on Heroku.  After `git push heroku master` I run `heroku open` and get the following error.  What does this it mean and how can I fix it?

```
(venv)peg@peg:~/Jungle-Flask$ heroku open
Opening jungle-monks... done
[1:1:0309/214907:ERROR:image_metadata_extractor.cc(111)] Couldn't load libexif.
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.
[14994:14994:0309/214907:ERROR:gl_implementation_osmesa.cc(22)] Failed to load libGL.so.1: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

requirements.txt

```
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-Bcrypt==0.6.0
Flask-Bootstrap==3.1.1.1
Flask-Login==0.2.10
Flask-Mail==0.9.0
Flask-Migrate==1.2.0
Flask-Moment==0.3.0
Flask-PageDown==0.1.4
Flask-SQLAlchemy==1.0
Flask-Script==0.6.7
Flask-Testing==0.4.2
Flask-WTF==0.9.4
Flask-WhooshAlchemy==0.55a
Jinja2==2.7.3
Mako==1.0.0
Markdown==2.4
MarkupSafe==0.23
PAM==0.4.2
Pillow==2.3.0
PsychoPy==1.80.07
Pygments==1.6
SQLAlchemy==0.9.3
Sphinx==1.2.2
Tempita==0.5.2
Twisted-Core==13.2.0
Twisted-Web==13.2.0
WTForms==1.0.5
Werkzeug==0.9.6
Whoosh==2.6.0
adium-theme-ubuntu==0.3.4
alembic==0.6.7
apt-xapian-index==0.45
argparse==1.2.1
bleach==1.4
blinker==1.3
chardet==2.0.1
colorama==0.2.5
command-not-found==0.3
coverage==3.7.1
debtagshw==0.1
decorator==3.4.0
defer==1.0.6
dirspec==13.10
dnspython==1.11.1
docutils==0.11
duplicity==0.6.23
flask-paginate==0.2.3
gunicorn==19.3.0
html5lib==0.999
httplib2==0.8
itsdangerous==0.24
lockfile==0.8
lxml==3.3.3
nose==1.3.1
oauthlib==0.6.1
oneconf==0.3.7
pbr==0.10.0
pexpect==3.1
piston-mini-client==0.7.5
psycopg2==2.4.5
py==1.4.20
pyOpenSSL==0.13
pycrypto==2.6.1
pycups==1.9.66
pycurl==7.19.3
pygobject==3.12.0
pyserial==2.6
pysmbc==1.0.14.1
pytest==2.5.1
python-apt==0.9.3.5ubuntu1
python-debian==0.1.21-nmu2ubuntu2
pyxdg==0.25
reportlab==3.0
requests==2.2.1
roman==2.0.0
sessioninstaller==0.0.0
six==1.5.2
software-center-aptd-plugins==0.0.0
sqlalchemy-migrate==0.9.2
sqlparse==0.1.14
system-service==0.1.6
unity-lens-photos==1.0
urllib3==1.7.1
virtualenv==1.11.4
wsgiref==0.1.2
wxPython==2.8.12.1
wxPython-common==2.8.12.1
xdiagnose==3.6.3build2
zope.interface==4.0.5
```

Comment: `libGL.so.1` refers to the [OpenGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL) library, which is a graphics library that is very unlikely to be installed on a server, particularly Heroku. It seems some of your dependencies currently depend on `gtk`, and in turn on OpenGL, which won't work on Heroku.

Comment: thanx @LukasGraf I will post my requirements will you know which one is use this Library? and do u know how can I solve this error?

Comment: Uhm, I can't say for sure, but `unity-lens-photos` and `wxPython` don't make much sense on a headless server, do they? Why do you have them as dependencies for a web application?

Comment: I just did pip freeze> requirements.txt and it comes to file @LukasGraf So if I delete it maybe helps?

Comment: Well, that entirely depends on whether you actually *need* (= use) these dependencies. If you just did `pip freeze` on your global system Python, you're going to get all kinds of unnecessary packages in that list. You need to develop your application in a *clean* `virtualenv` that contains nothing else than the dependencies your application needs. I wrote [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19877478/1599111) a while ago that may help you with this.