# Removing old egg-info files on Python package setup

Tags: python, python-2.7, distutils, setup.py, egg

I have very basic Python setup scripts that just call `distutils.core.setup()` with relevant parameters. The packages are for internal use only, so I do not need much more than that at the moment.

What bugs me is that when a new version of a package is installed, the old `egg-info` files are not automatically removed - although the package directory is overwritten with the new version.

(1) Is there a reason for not removing the old files by default?

(2) Is there a recommended way to remove the old `egg-info` files on new version setup so that it won't cause me grief later when the setup process becomes more complicated?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This causes problems for me when installing packages with git-revisions in their version numbers. pkg_resources.get_distribution("package") then returns the version that sorts highest, rather than the most recently (and therefore active) installed revision

Answer (score 3):

I've had issues with `egg-info` files using the distutils package as well. I think currently the recommended package for this is setuptools. My switch to setuptools fixed the problems I had with old egg-info files. So I would advice to use `setuptools.setup()` instead of `distutils.core.setup()`. See this post for more information:

[Differences between distribute, distutils, setuptools and distutils2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344076/differences-between-distribute-distutils-setuptools-and-distutils2)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I am working on a different project now it may take me a couple of weeks to try this out.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and I'm using setuptools.