# What is the relationship between pip, pyinstall and easy_install?

Tags: python, pip, easy-install

It seems to me that `easy_install` was forked, renamed to `pyinstall`, forked again and renamed to `pip`. Is that right? Are there any sources for it?

Are `easy_install` / `pyinstall` still used?

(I have found https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller and https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyinstall which seem to support this)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220404/why-use-pip-over-easy-install

Comment: [Differences between distribute, distutils, setuptools and distutils2?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6344076/562769) is a nice resource, but it does not answer the relationship between those three package managers.

Comment: I suspect that the answer to the question of whether `easy_install` is still used is: it is often used to install `pip`

Answer (score 3):

`easy_install` still exists, but is largely deprecated due to basically not being as good as `pip` (see discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220404/why-use-pip-over-easy-install)). `pyinstall` is just the old name for `pip`; it's obsolete.

More discussion on `pip` vs. `easy_install` [here](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/pip_easy_install.html).