# sdist correct but pip install no static

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, pypi

I am trying to deliver a Django app via pip (stored on Pypi).
The problem is that when I install the app with pip, it does not contain the static folder inside of the main specified package.

Here is what I have:

```
├── LICENSE.txt
├── MANIFEST.in
├── README.rst
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
└── zxcvbn_password
    ├── fields.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── static
    │   └── zxcvbn_password
    │       └── js
    │           ├── password_strength.js
    │           ├── zxcvbn-async.js
    │           └── zxcvbn.js
    ├── validators.py
    └── widgets.py
```

What I do is the following:

```
python setup.py register -r pypi
python setup.py sdist upload -r pypi
```

The tar archive is correctly created (it contains the static folder), and when I download this same archive from PyPi, it also contains the static folder. But installing it with pip just gives me the following in `zxcvbn_password` inside my site-packages:

```
└── zxcvbn_password
    ├── fields.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── validators.py
    └── widgets.py
```

This is how I write my setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name='django-zxcvbn-password',
    packages=['zxcvbn_password'],
    include_package_data=True,
    url='https://github.com/Pawamoy/django-zxcvbn-password',
    # and other data ...
)
```

And my MANIFEST.in:

```
include LICENSE.txt
include README.rst
recursive-include zxcvbn_password/static *
```

Am I doing something wrong?
Why the static folder is not installed when pip uses `setup.py install`?

### Edit

I added the line of setup.py importing the setup function from distutils.
I get this warning when running `python setup.py sdist upload -r pypitest`:
`/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'include_package_data'`

Comment: Not sure what cause this but have you tried ìnclude static` in the manifest. Also check out this: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/distributing.html

Comment: Consider self-answering your question instead of adding your solution to the question. Here on SE, the goal is to provide a somewhat comprehensive QA archive. If you find a solution to your problem, self-answering is perfectly fine and encouraged as it may help others to find a solution to your question.

Comment: Okay fine, I will do this, thanks for your explanation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution with Distutils

```
# MANIFEST.in

include LICENSE.txt
include README.rst
# recursive-include zxcvbn_password/static *
```

and

```
# setup.py

from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name='django-zxcvbn-password',
    packages=['zxcvbn_password'],
    package_data={'': ['static/zxcvbn_password/js/*.js']},
    # include_package_data=True,
    url='https://github.com/Pawamoy/django-zxcvbn-password',
    # and other data ...
)
```

I commented out the recursive-include line from MANIFEST.in and the include_package_data=True from setup.py: apparently they are not needed if you specify the package_data={...} line in setup.py.

### Solution with Setuptools

```
# MANIFEST.in

include LICENSE.txt
include README.rst
recursive-include zxcvbn_password/static *
```

and

```
# setup.py

from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='django-zxcvbn-password',
    packages=['zxcvbn_password'],
    include_package_data=True,
    url='https://github.com/Pawamoy/django-zxcvbn-password',
    # and other data ...
)
```

The only line that has changed is `from setuptools import setup`.

### Conclusion

My problem was trully coming from the way I was importing the setup function.
Reading this: [Differences between distribute, distutils, setuptools and distutils2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344076/differences-between-distribute-distutils-setuptools-and-distutils2), I understood that Setuptools has more functionality than Distutils.