# Sharing a python script with module requirements?

Tags: python, pip

I'm new to python and was curious if python had something like an `npm install` that would pip install the required packages for a script I have.  I've looked into the `setup.py` readme and it looks like its mostly geared to creating a tarball to send to pip, which isn't what I want.

I'd like to be able to check out the source code and then just run it.  As it stands when I ask my coworkers to use the script they run into import failures and have to manually pip install things which is a poor experience.

My setup.py file is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from distutils.core import setup

setup(name='Add-Webhook',
      version='1.0',
      description='Adds webhooks to git repos',
      author='devshorts',
      packages=['requests'],
     )
```

And when I run it it

```
$ python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
error: package directory 'requests' does not exist
```

I have a small script that sits next to the setup.py that uses the `requests` package and I'd like for it to be installed on 'install'

```
$ ls
total 40
-rw-r--r--  1 akropp  JOMAX\Domain Users  1039 Feb 24 09:51 README.md
-rwxr-xr-x  1 akropp  JOMAX\Domain Users  4489 Feb 27 17:01 add-webhook.py
-rw-r--r--  1 akropp  JOMAX\Domain Users   391 Feb 23 14:24 github.iml
-rw-r--r--  1 akropp  JOMAX\Domain Users   213 Apr  8 15:06 setup.py
```

Comment: You can specify dependencies in a `setup.py`, if that's what you mean, then `python setup.py install` will install those too. Alternatively, if there's not too much installation required for your script, provide a [requirements file](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user_guide.html#requirements-files) with it so they can more conveniently install everything in one go.

Comment: I put in the dependencies there but when I do `python setup.py` it complains that the module folders aren't there. I'd like for it to just install if its missing, something like the way npm does it? Not sure what I'm missing

Comment: If your `setup.py` isn't working, perhaps you could share it, along with the complaints you're seeing? It's hard to provide helpful suggestions without seeing what you're working with; a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is always appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create `requirements.txt` file in your project's root directory, and add necessary Python packages with the versions you need.

Then just run `$pip install -r requirements.txt` to install everything that you have specified in `requirements.txt` file.

Not sure if this is what you need, but this is something better than running `$pip install <package name>` for several times.

Comment: That works, is this the idiomatic way of dealing with package distribution in python?

Comment: A solution without pip? It looks like the way to go is with source with the OP

Comment: Having `pip` replaced `easy_install` for installing python packages, yes. I'm sure there are other ways around, but this is the default method when dealing with python packages via pip.

Comment: @devshorts many packages you see on GitHub and elsewhere will have both `setup.py` and `requirements.txt` - often the former includes the minimal requirements for actually using the package, whereas the latter includes extra modules used for actual development (e.g. `pylint`, `sphinx`, ...).

Comment: @devshorts no problem. Note that if you've used a `virtualenv` to set up your development environment so that it only contains what's needed for this package, you can use `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to easily create the requirements file.

Answer (score 3):

You have misunderstood the parameters for `setup`. The `packages` parameter is for specifying the packages that **you are providing**, not the dependencies of those packages.

Per [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#relationships-between-distributions-and-packages):

> Dependencies on other Python modules and packages can be specified by supplying the *requires* keyword argument to `setup()`. The value must be a list of strings. Each string specifies a package that is required, and optionally what versions are sufficient.

You could also consider using [`setuptools`](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools) instead of `distutils` (switch to `from setuptools import setup`) and specifying `install_requires` (see [the docs on dependency declarations](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#declaring-dependencies)) - see e.g. [Differences between distribute, distutils, setuptools and distutils2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6344076/3001761)