# an alternative to setup.py

Tags: python, setup.py, pypi

`setup.py` has one significant problem:

- it can not be parsed securely

This leads to a lot of problems - it can not be securely analysed, reading 100k+ packages from PyPI requires too much overhead, source packages can not be automatically converted to native system formats like Debian and Fedora etc.

So, are there any alternatives for packaging Python source that use static data format (not setup.py) for describing and wrapping their contents? So that a `source package` is just a .zip file of source checkout, which does not require magic with build steps.

Comment: I fear the current answer is "no".

Comment: setuptools maybe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344076/differences-between-distribute-distutils-setuptools-and-distutils2

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but you can create an rpm with `python setup.py bdist_rpm`.  Not deb though.

Comment: If you are pulling packages from PyPI without audit you already have a security risk; somebody with a debian keyring needs to decide that it is a trusted package.

Answer (score 1):

Back when this question was asked the answer was no. Several PEPs existed to try and standardize metadata (and by extension most information required for installing). These had follow-ups *after* the question was asked, which has since evolved into solutions like `pyproject.toml` and `setup.cfg` which nowadays allow `setup.py`-less installation of your packages which is even adopted and encouraged by tools like [PyPA's Flit](https://flit.pypa.io/en/stable/index.html).

That said, packages not leveraging these possibilities will still exist, and if they have a `setup.py` you can't control, they'll be running arbitrary code nonetheless and you'll have to decide if you trust the authors and the community for reporting malicious packages.

Answer (score 0):

Python wheels are the answer to the problems you describe: http://pythonwheels.com/

However, at the time of writing many projects do not supply wheels (but you can build them yourself.)