# Distributing set of python files as a single executable

Tags: python

I have a python script, distributed across several files, all within a single directory. I would like to distribute this as a single executable file (for linux systems, mainly), such that the file can be moved around and copied easily.

I've come as far as renaming my main file to `__main__.py`, and zipping everything into `myscript.zip`, so now I can run `python myscript.zip`. But that's one step too short. I want to run this as `./myscript`, without creating an alias or a wrapper script.

Is this possible at all? What's the best way? I thought that maybe the zip file could be embedded in a (ba)sh script, that passes it to python (but without creating a temporary file, if possible).

EDIT:
After having another go at `setuptools` (I had not managed to make it work before), I could create sort of self-contained script, an "[eggsecutable script](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#eggsecutable-scripts)". The trick is that in this case you cannot have your main module named `__main__.py`. Then there are still a couple of issues: the resulting script cannot be renamed and it still creates the `__pycache__` directory when run. I solved these by modifying the shell-script code at the beginning of the file, and adding the `-B` flag to the python command there.

EDIT (2): Not that easy either, it was working because I still had my source `.py` files next to the "eggsecutable", move something and it stops working.

Comment: You might want to have a look at `setuptools`, more specifically [Automatic Script Creation](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation). Other [Python packaging tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344076/differences-between-distribute-distutils-setuptools-and-distutils2) have similar constructs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another less hackish solution (I'm sorry for answering my own question twice, but this doesn't fit in a comment, and I think it is better in a separate box).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

modules = [
  [ 'my_aux', '''
def my_aux():
  return 7
'''],
  ['my_func', '''
from my_aux import my_aux
def my_func():
  print("and I'm my_func: {0}".format(my_aux()))
'''],
  ['my_script', '''
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import (unicode_literals, division, absolute_import, print_function)
import sys
def main(my_name):
  import my_aux
  print("Hello, I'm my_script: {0}".format(my_name))
  print(my_aux.my_aux())
  import my_func
  my_func.my_func()
if (__name__ == '__main__'):
  sys.exit(main(__file__))
'''],
]

import sys, types
for m in modules:
  module = types.ModuleType(m[0])
  exec(m[1], module.__dict__)
  sys.modules[m[0]] = module
del modules

from my_script import main

main(__file__)
```

I think this is more clear, although probably less efficient. All the needed files are included as strings (they could be zipped and b64-encoded first, for space efficiency). Then they are imported as modules and the main method is run. Care should be taken to define the modules in the right order.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the raw zip file as a binary and insert the shebang into the first line.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
PK...rest of the zip
```

Of course you need an appropriate editor for this, that can handle binary files (e.g.: `vim -b`) or you can make it with a small bash script.

```
{ echo '#!/usr/bin/env python'; cat myscript.zip; } > myscript
chmod +x myscript
./myscript
```

Comment: That's of course easier than my solution. I tried this before and it didn't work, but that's because I didn't use the proper tool (`vim -b`). The problem is I don't know how to get the actual file name from within the script, as `__file__` gives the name within the zip.

Comment: @Jellby `__file__` gives `./myscript/__main__.py` for me. You could extract the script name from that. Also `sys.argv` gives `['./myscript']`.

Comment: You could also the a look at what py.test does with `py.test --genscript=script`. It creates a self-contained script with the wrapped source in base64 inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there's the obligatory "thus isn't the way things are normally done, are you sure you want to do it THIS way?" warning. That said, to answer your question and not try to substitute it with what someone else thinks you should do...

You can write a script, and prepend it to a python egg. The script would extract the egg from itself, and obviously call exit before the egg file data is encountered. Egg files are importable but not executable, so the script would have to

1. Extract the egg from itself as an egg file with a known name in the current directory
2. Run `python -m egg`
3. Delete the file
4. Exit

Sorry, I'm on a phone at the moment, so I'll update with actual code later

Comment: Are you still on the phone? What is the normal way?

Comment: Distribution would normally be done with a setuptools created zip or tar.gz, or these days a wheel file. I was  saying that distribution via executables is unusual in and of itself

Comment: And yes, actually, still on a phone :)

Answer (score 0):

Continuing my own attempts, I concocted something that works for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import glob, os.path

from setuptools import setup

files = [os.path.splitext(x)[0] for x in glob.glob('*.py')]
thisfile = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(__file__))[0]
files.remove(thisfile)

setup(
  script_args=['bdist_wheel', '-d', '.'],
  py_modules=files,
)

# Now try to make the package runnable:
# Add the self-running trick code to the top of the file,
# rename it and make it executable

import sys, os, stat

exe_name = 'my_module'
magic_code = '''#!/bin/sh
name=`readlink -f "$0"`
exec {0} -c "import sys, os; sys.path.insert(0, '$name'); from my_module import main; sys.exit(main(my_name='$name'))" "$@"
'''.format(sys.executable)

wheel = glob.glob('*.whl')[0]
with open(exe_name, 'wb') as new:
  new.write(bytes(magic_code, 'ascii'))
  with open(wheel, 'rb') as original:
    data = True
    while (data):
      data = original.read(4096)
      new.write(data)
os.remove(wheel)
st = os.stat(exe_name)
os.chmod(exe_name, st.st_mode | stat.S_IEXEC)
```

This creates a wheel with all *.py files in the current directory (except itself), and then adds the code to make it executable. `exe_name` is the final name of the file, and the `from my_module import main; sys.exit(main(my_name='$name'))` should be modified depending on each script, in my case I want to call the `main` method from `my_module.py`, which takes an argument `my_name` (the name of the actual file being run).

There's no guarantee this will run in a system different from the one it was created, but it is still useful to create a self-contained file from the sources (to be placed in `~/bin`, for instance).