# Using an alternative index with `setup.py install`?

Tags: python, package, setup.py

I downloaded a Python `.tar.gz` package and extracted it. I'm working in a closed LAN so obviously the usual global PyPI index isn't available. We have our own PyPI index in the network.

I know how I can link to it when using `pip` or `easy_install`. However I couldn't find out how to do this when running `setup.py install` directly.

How can this be done?

Comment: Have you tried doing the same thing? I think `setup.py` passes all arguments on to `pip`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Actually, it's the other way around: `pip` is a user-friendly tool based on setuptools/distutils. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344076/differences-between-distribute-distutils-setuptools-and-distutils2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build a package and install it from archive file using pip.

1. Configure pip to use another index according to [this article](https://jacobian.org/writing/when-pypi-goes-down/). Open `~/.pip/pip.conf` and add:

   ```
   [global]
   index-url = http://your-private-index
   ```
2. Build a package:

   ```
   python setup.py build sdist
   ```
3. And finally, install package using pip

   ```
   pip install dist/mypackage-1.0.0.tar.gz
   ```

Comment: Can I use `pip install --index http://my-pypi/simple` instead of configuring `pip` globally?

Comment: It does the same thing.

Comment: If you're going to use `pip`, why not skip 1 and 2 and use `pip install --i`?

Comment: @juanchopanza I assumed (probably incorrectly) that the package is under active development and Aviv wanted to install a debug version he is working on. If it's just some package from PyPI, then of course the best way is to upload it to local package index and install with `pip install` as usual.

Comment: "I know how I can link to it when using pip or easy_install. However I couldn't find out how to do this when running setup.py install directly."