# Error in caching a simple RDD with pyspark while without caching the code works fine (How to make a class picklable in a notebook)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, pickle, databricks

I have the following simple code causing an error regarding caching:

```py
trips_in = sc.textFile("trip_data.csv")
trips = trips_in.map(lambda l: l.split(",")).map(lambda x: parseTrip(x)).cache()

trips.count()
```

The function `parseTrip()` gets a list of strings and creates and returns a class Trip:

```py
class Trip:
  def __init__(self, id, duration):
    self.id = id
    self.duration = duration
```

I get the error right after the action `count()`. However, if I remove the `cache()` at the end of second line everything work fine. 
According to the error the problem is that the class Trip can not be pickled:

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle __main__.Trip: attribute lookup __main__.Trip failed
```

So how can I make it picklable (if it is an actual word)? 
Note that I am using a Databricks notebook so I can not make a separate .py for class definition to make it picklable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environment does not affect the answer - if you want to use custom classes it has to be importable on every node in the cluster.

- For a single module you can easily use `SparkContext.addPyFile` with URL to a [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/) (or another supported format: "[*file in HDFS (or other Hadoop-supported filesystems), or an
  HTTP, HTTPS or FTP URI*](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.SparkContext.addPyFile)")

  - Create a gist.
  - Click on Raw link and copy URL.
  - In your notebook call:

    ```
    sc.addPyFile(raw_gist_url)
    ```
- For complex dependencies you distribute egg files.

  - Create [Python package](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html) [using `setuptools`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344076/differences-between-distribute-distutils-setuptools-and-distutils2#14753678).

    Directory structure:

    ```
    .
    ├── setup.py
    └── trip
        └── __init__.py
    ```

    Example setup file:

    ```
    #!/usr/bin/env python

    from setuptools import setup

    setup(name='trip',
          version='0.0.1',
          description='Trip',
          author='Jane Doe',
          author_email='jane@example.com',
          url='https://example.com',
          packages=['trip'],)
    ```
  - Create egg file:

    ```
    python setup.py bdist_egg
    ```

    This will create `dist` directory with `trip-0.0.1-pyX.Y.egg` file
  - Go to Databricks dashboard -> New -> Libary and upload egg file from dist directory:

    [image]
  - Attach library to the cluster you want to use.
- Finally if all you want is a record type you can use `namedtuple` without any additional steps:

  ```
  from collections import namedtuple

  Trip = namedtuple('Trip', ['id', 'duration'])
  ```