# Upload python package without rebuild

Tags: python, distutils

I would like to build a python package, run tests against the build artifact and then upload the python package to a PyPI w/o re-building the package.

We are building a CI/CD pipeline and want to make sure that the exact package we built and tested is what gets published, not a re-built version after the fact.

Currently, if I run the following:

```
$ python setup.py egg_info -b .$BUILD_NUM sdist bdist_wheel
```

Then run my tests and run:

```
$ python setup.py egg_info -b .$BUILD_NUM sdist bdist_wheel upload
```

Then the timestamp on the files shows the file was re-built the second time.

Is there a way to submit the files without re-building them?

Comment: Perhaps remove `sdist bdist_wheel` when you do the upload? Those commands sound like you are asking for a rebuild

Comment: You may want to add a tag indicating whether you are using distutils or setuptools.

Comment: Returns `error: No dist file created in earlier command`. From what I can tell you are required to specify the distributions you want uploaded as part of the command: https://docs.python.org/2.7/distutils/packageindex.html#the-upload-command

Comment: So using distutils?

Comment: A simple hack would be to just rerun the tests after uploading to make sure that it's all still kosher.

Comment: I assumed it might be something like that. I might also just run the tests w/o packaging/uploading until after I have confirmed tests are passing.

Comment: BTW, what does distutils have to do with it? What are my other options?

Comment: Your other option is [setuptools](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and also [distutils2](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Distutils2). See https://stackoverflow.com/q/6344076/2988730

Answer (score 2):

By using `sdist` and `bdist_wheel` in your command you explicitly order `setup.py` to rebuild packages. If you want to upload without rebuilding just use `python setup.py upload`. Or even better, use [twine](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twine); it's **the** recommended way to upload to PyPI.

```
twine upload dist/*
```

twine looks into `dist`, gets the package name and version and uploads packages.